# Which HTML elements can receive focus?

Tags: html, focus

I'm looking for a definitive list of HTML elements which are allowed to take focus, i.e. which elements will be put into focus when `focus()` is called on them?

I'm writing a jQuery extension which works on elements that can be brought into focus. I hope the answer to this question will allow me to be specific about the elements I target.

Answer (score 406, accepted):

There isn't a definite list, it's up to the browser. The only standard we have is [DOM Level 2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html), according to which the only elements that have a `focus()` method are
`HTMLInputElement`, `HTMLSelectElement`, `HTMLTextAreaElement` and `HTMLAnchorElement`. This notably omits `HTMLButtonElement` and `HTMLAreaElement`.

Today's browsers define `focus()` on HTMLElement, but an element won't actually take focus unless it's one of:

- HTMLAnchorElement/HTMLAreaElement with an href
- HTMLInputElement/HTMLSelectElement/HTMLTextAreaElement/HTMLButtonElement but not with `disabled` (IE actually gives you an error if you try), and file uploads have unusual behaviour for security reasons
- HTMLIFrameElement (though focusing it doesn't do anything useful). Other embedding elements also, maybe, I haven't tested them all.
- Any element with a `tabindex`

There are likely to be other subtle exceptions and additions to this behaviour depending on browser.

Comment: Any idea how to get all of these with jQuery? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668525/is-there-a-jquery-selector-to-get-all-elements-that-can-get-focus

Comment: I found some interesting results: http://jsfiddle.net/B7gn6/
suggests to me that the "tabindex" attrib is not enough to work in Chrome at least..

Comment: @jon: those tabindex elements do actually accept focus, though, if you try clicking them. Testing `.is(':focus')` is not reliable - jQuery implements its own test for `:focus` on Chrome, which is what you're actually testing here. That jQuery code is unreliable/buggy (`~tabIndex`..?! That ain't gonna work...)

Comment: @bobince Really interesting. +1 for the last point i.e. usage of `tabIndex` for elements that doesn't support `focus` by default. Really very useful. Wanted to give you +10 if I could.

Comment: That the tabindex attribute "allows authors to control whether an element is supposed to be focusable" is standardized in HTML5: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute Basically, a value of 0 makes the element focusable but leaves its ordering up to the browser.

Comment: Very helpful thank you. If you only need to focus temporarily and don't want to retain the tabindex, you can do something like this in jQuery: $('#el').attr('tabindex', 1).focus().blur(function() {$(this).attr('tabindex', null)});

Comment: All elements with `element.isContentEditable === true` are focusable too.
Note that IE -10 (11+?) can focus any element with display block or table (div, span, etc.).

Comment: `$("#filenameInput").click();` kills IE submit()

Comment: An element with a tabindex of -1 may receive focus programmatically through the focus method; it just can't be tabbed to.

Comment: like @mems says, IE allows focusing other elements under certain conditions. We had a weird bug at our company because a container DIV was getting a `focus` before the child ever got a `click`. The answer is good but should be edited to contain this.

Comment: Thanks, @natevw, for the link. Our fellow developers may also find this doc useful, which includes a discussion of the way `tabIndex` has been standardised in HTML5 (according to Mozilla, anyhow): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Keyboard-navigable_JavaScript_widgets

Comment: …unless the tabindex is -1, which makes focus impossible >> not true, if tabindex is -1, focusing by CLICKING is possible, but focusing by pressing "tab" is impossible. -1 makes an element focusable, just it isn't added in the tabbing order. See: http://jsfiddle.net/0jz0kd1a/ , first try to click the element, then change tabindex to 0 and try to use tab.

Comment: `tabindex` doesn't seem to let `form` receive focus, at least in Firefox.

Comment: Important point  jessebeach makes. The answer is misleading at the end when it says: "…unless the tabindex is -1, which makes focus impossible." This isn't true. You can use `.focus()` to focus elements with `tabindex="-1"` it just means they won't be in the tabbing order that's all and that's true for all modern browsers i've tested on. Please update?

Comment: Unfortunately, a quick glance at MDN shows tab-index focusing is better supported by some browsers than others.

Comment: For anyone still coming to this answer, I found that I had to add a `tabindex` in Chrome for my `<p>` to receive focus even when it had `contenteditable=true`.  Without that, Chrome never focused the paragraph and always returned the `<body>` as the `activeElement`.

Comment: The `<body>` element is missing from the list of focusable elements.

Answer (score 54):

Here I have a CSS-selector based on [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus/#answer-1600194) to select any focusable HTML element:

```
  a[href]:not([tabindex='-1']),
  area[href]:not([tabindex='-1']),
  input:not([disabled]):not([tabindex='-1']),
  select:not([disabled]):not([tabindex='-1']),
  textarea:not([disabled]):not([tabindex='-1']),
  button:not([disabled]):not([tabindex='-1']),
  iframe:not([tabindex='-1']),
  [tabindex]:not([tabindex='-1']),
  [contentEditable=true]:not([tabindex='-1'])
  {
      /* your CSS for focusable elements goes here */
  }
```

or a little more beautiful in SASS:

```
a[href],
area[href],
input:not([disabled]),
select:not([disabled]),
textarea:not([disabled]),
button:not([disabled]),
iframe,
[tabindex],
[contentEditable=true]
{
    &:not([tabindex='-1'])
    {
        /* your SCSS for focusable elements goes here */
    }
}
```

I've added it as an answer, because that was, what I was looking for, when Google redirected me to this Stackoverflow question.

**EDIT:** There is one more selector, which is focusable:

```
[contentEditable=true]
```

However, this is used very rarely.

Comment: @TWiStErRob - your selector doesn't target the same elements as @ReeCube's selectors, because yours does not include elements that don't have a tabindex explicitly set. For example `<a href="foo.html">Bar</a>` is certainly focusable because it's an `a` element that has an `href` attribute. But your selector does not include it.

Comment: @jbyrd that was just a call for edit based on bobince's statement: "…unless the tabindex is -1, which makes focus impossible.", it was never supposed to replace ReeCube's answer; see the edit history.

Comment: SASS (or CSS) is a suitable form to provide a rigorous answer to the above question (barring browser inconsistencies).

Comment: `tabindex="-1"` does **not** make an element unfocusable, it just can't be focused by tabbing. It still may receive focus by clicking on it or programmatically with `HTMLElement.focus()`; same for any other negative number. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Comment: I wouldnt exclude items with tabindex-1. Users won't be able to focus via any input devices, but you may want to programmatically set and show that focus still.

Comment: I would recommend using `input:not([type="hidden"])`, unless you want the selector to focus an element that is visually and screen-reader hidden by browser default

Answer (score 14):

```
$focusable:
  'a[href]',
  'area[href]',
  'button',
  'details',
  'input',
  'iframe',
  'select',
  'textarea',

  // these are actually case sensitive but i'm not listing out all the possible variants
  '[contentEditable=""]',
  '[contentEditable="true"]',
  '[contentEditable="TRUE"]',

  '[tabindex]:not([tabindex^="-"])',
  ':not([disabled])';
```

I'm creating a SCSS list of all focusable elements and I thought this might help someone due to this question's Google rank.

A few things to note:

- I changed `:not([tabindex="-1"])` to `:not([tabindex^="-"])` because it's perfectly plausible to generate `-2` somehow. Better safe than sorry right?
- Adding `:not([tabindex^="-"])` to all the other focusable selectors is completely pointless. When using `[tabindex]:not([tabindex^="-"])` it already includes all elements that you'd be negating with `:not`!
- I included `:not([disabled])` because disabled elements can *never* be focusable. So again it's useless to add it to every single element.

Comment: The part about not having to add `:not([disabled])` on every line is wrong.  Don't believe me?  Do a `document.querySelectorAll(':not([disabled])')` and see what happens.  Not disabled means you want all the enabled elements.

Comment: Similarly the part about not having to add `:not([tabindex^="-"]`. 


Proof: Try this line in your console:
`document.querySelectorAll('a, [tabindex]:not([tabindex="-1"]')[0]`

It will select a node such as `<a href="shouldnt-be-focused" tabindex="-1">nope</a>`

For what it's worth I think this comes from the misunderstanding that these selectors are joined by "or" and not "and", so as soon as the <a> tag is encountered it satisfies the selector

Answer (score 11):

The [ally.js](https://allyjs.io/) accessibility library provides an unofficial, test-based list here:

https://allyjs.io/data-tables/focusable.html

(NB: Their page doesn't say how often tests were performed.)

Answer (score 7):

Maybe this one can help:

```js
function focus(el){
 el.focus();
 return el==document.activeElement;
}
```

return value: true = success, false = failed

Reff:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/activeElement
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus

Comment: It works, but it loses current focus state. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a much more elegant way to handle this:

Extend the element prototype like the sample below.
Then you can use it like:

```
element.isFocusable()
```

*Returns **true** if "element" is focusable and **false** if not.

```js
/**
* Determining if an element can be focused on
* @return   {Boolean}
*/
HTMLElement.prototype.isFocusable = function () {
  var current = document.activeElement
  if (current === this) return true
  var protectEvent = (e) => e.stopImmediatePropagation()
  this.addEventListener("focus", protectEvent, true)
  this.addEventListener("blur", protectEvent, true)
  this.focus({preventScroll:true})
  var result = document.activeElement === this
  this.blur()
  if (current) current.focus({preventScroll:true})
  this.removeEventListener("focus", protectEvent, true)
  this.removeEventListener("blur", protectEvent, true)
  return result
}

// A SIMPLE TEST
console.log(document.querySelector('a').isFocusable())
console.log(document.querySelector('a[href]').isFocusable())
```

```html
<a>Not focusable</a>
<a href="#">Focusable</a>
```

Comment: Do you mind if there is something like "onfocus" function too? - any function that do a trick by UI will make disappointment soon.

Comment: Are you asking for a focus event listener? like this -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event

Comment: No dear, i am telling you that way of your function can make mistakes, for example if there be focus event added to the element, it will run while the developer going to check the element is focus-able or not.

Comment: That's not an issue dear, you can easily add an event protector function to focus and blur and remove it later on. I added it for you there, dear.

Comment: Better but still an issue, if the element have a **passive** EventListener like the one that we add temporary, it will run before the stopImmediatePropagation() work - also look like Safari not support preventScroll yet

Comment: Safari supports it just fine. However, it has a proposed bug in some particular cases that will not occur in this case.

Comment: As for the passive event listener, you can take care of it the same way, create an event protector function for passive listeners. I leave that to you, dear. Just add that yourself, and any other requirement you might have in case you wanted to use this.

Comment: Sadly, no way to the handle the passive (your function protector is already passive) and still i think these kind of ways are not safe. Thanks, my goal was to clarify the issue, not helping myself. Your nice effort are admirable, i think this answer should get up-vote  more.

Comment: I must admit to a degree that it ain't peachy using UI stuff, thanks a bunch anyways.

Comment: This is indeed an elegant solution. Good job! The only question I have is shouldn't we register event protectors for other focus-related events like `focusin`, `focusout` as well? And also shouldn't we add event protectors for `current` as well?

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```js
function isFocusable(el) {
    const cs = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);
    if (cs.getPropertyValue('visibility') == 'hidden' || cs.getPropertyValue('display') == 'none')
        return false;
    const natively = 'a[href], area[href], details, iframe, :is(button, input:not([type="hidden"]), select, textarea)';
    
    if (el.matches(natively) || (el.hasAttribute('tabindex') && parseInt(el.getAttribute('tabindex')) >= 0) || el.isContentEditable)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

```css
*:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    border: 4px solid red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #FF5722;
}
```

```html
<a id="e1" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-pressed="false">TOGGLE</a>

<span id="not-focusable">NOT FOCUSABLE</span>

<span id="e3" role="button">ACTION</span>

<button id="e4" aria-pressed="false">REAL BUTTON TOGGLE</button>

<button>REAL BUTTON ACTION</button>

<script>
const log = (ev) => {console.log('Focusable?', ev.target, isFocusable(ev.target) )}


document.getElementById('e1').addEventListener('click',  log)
document.getElementById('not-focusable').addEventListener('click',  log)
document.getElementById('e3').addEventListener('click',  log)
document.getElementById('e4').addEventListener('click',  log)

</script>
```