# What is the difference between :focus and :active?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

What is the difference between the `:focus` and `:active` pseudo-classes?

Answer (score 559, accepted):

`:focus` and `:active` are two different states.

- `:focus` represents the state when the element is currently selected to receive input and
- `:active` represents the state when the element is currently being activated by the user.

For example let's say we have a `<button>`. The `<button>` will not have any state to begin with. It just exists. If we use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to give "focus" to the `<button>`, it now enters its `:focus` state. If you then click (or press <kbd>space</kbd>), you then make the button enter its (`:active`) state.

On that note, when you click on an element, you give it focus, which also cultivates the illusion that `:focus` and `:active` are the same. **They are not the same.** When clicked the button is in `:focus:active` state.

An example:

```html
<style type="text/css">
  button { font-weight: normal; color: black; }
  button:focus { color: red; }
  button:active { font-weight: bold; }
</style>
  
<button>
  When clicked, my text turns red AND bold!<br />
  But not when focused only,<br />
 where my text just turns red
</button>
```

edit: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NCwvj/)

Comment: Also note that you can get the focused element by using the confusingly named `document.activeElement` property, although it needs to be in a try catch because IE8 can throw an exception.

And be aware that older versions of browsers may treat :active and :focus differently.

`function activeElement() {
 try {
  return document.activeElement; /* can get exeption in IE8 */
 } catch(e) {
 }
}`

Comment: I've created a JSFiddle of your example here: http://jsfiddle.net/NCwvj/


Testing in chrome (v24) I've noticed that clicking the button only invokes the `:active` state

Comment: Nit: the order of focus and active affects the state of a HTML button if there is no :active:focus state - Putting :active state after :focus, I get the active changes when I hit tab and hit space. If :focus is last, I never see the active state.

Comment: @GauntFace, What browser are you using? On Chrome, the order of your `focus` and `active` declaration doesn't matter. It only matters when they contradict each other e.g. `color:red` and `color:blue` (then last one wins).

Comment: Related question and the answer, based on this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48597351/5587480. From my point of view, very easy to understand

Comment: Thanks for the **`:focus:active`** state comment. Didn't know that these are different from both `:focus` and `:active`, it's a third state... awesome!

Comment: So to me `:active` seems to work a bit like `:visited` (for a button instead of a link).

Answer (score 68):

```
:active       Adds a style to an element that is activated
:focus        Adds a style to an element that has keyboard input focus
:hover        Adds a style to an element when you mouse over it
:lang         Adds a style to an element with a specific lang attribute
:link         Adds a style to an unvisited link
:visited      Adds a style to a visited link
```

Source: [CSS Pseudo-classes](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

Comment: While related, this doesn't answer the question

Comment: @GregorWeber it expose difference by showing definitions

Comment: You probably know this, but if you define them in that order `visited` links will not change style when hovered or clicked because their "visitedness" will override the other pseudo-classes. [LVHFA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383486/2454914) is the order most people will want to use in most cases. Not sure why you included `lang`...

Comment: Sorry, I know that it's an old answer, but I'm not sure about the definition for the `focus` state. It's not only about keyboard, if I click on a button, it will also gain focus.

Answer (score 41):

There are four cases.

1. By default, active and focus are both off.
2. When you *tab* to cycle through *focusable elements*, they will enter `:focus` (without active).
3. When you *click* on a *non-focusable element*, it enters `:active` (without focus).
4. When you *click* on a *focusable element* it enters `:active:focus` (active and focus simultaneously).

*Example:*

```
<div>
  I cannot be focused.
</div>

<div tabindex="0">
  I am focusable.
</div>
```

---

```
div:focus {
  background: green;
}

div:active {
  color: orange;
}

div:focus:active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

When the page loads both are in case 1. When you press tab you will focus the second div and see it exhibit case 2. When you click on the first div you see case 3. When you click the second div, you see case 4.

---

Whether an element is focusable or not is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1600194). Most are not by default. But, it's safe to assume `<a>`, `<input>`, `<textarea>` are focusable by default.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out how elements can have `:active` but not `:focus`. That's one thing I was confused about that the other answers did not address.

Answer (score 12):

:focus is when an element is able to accept input - the cursor in a input box or a link that has been tabbed to.

:active is when an element is being activated by a user - the time between when a user presses a mouse button and then releases it.

Comment: Hi! Is there a state for "currently clicked"? Lets say there are three links in the nav menu, how do you get it to keep a certain color when currently "on" the link? to show the user where he currently is. as :active only works as long as the link (in this case) is being clicked, but changes back on mouse button-release.

Answer (score 1):

Active is when the user activating that point (Like mouse clicking, if we use tab from field-to-field there is no sign from active style. Maybe clicking need more time, just try hold click on that point), focus is happened after the point is activated. Try this :

```
<style type="text/css">
  input { font-weight: normal; color: black; }
  input:focus { color: green; outline: 1px solid green; }
  input:active { color: red; outline: 1px solid red; }
</style>

<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
```

Answer (score -3):

Focus can only be given by keyboard input, but an Element can be activated by both, a mouse or a keyboard.

If one would use :focus on a link, the style rule would only apply with pressing a botton on the keyboard.

Comment: `:focus` doesn't work like that. The textarea I'm typing in currently has focus because I clicked a button. It also can lose and restore focus by clicking out of it, and into it again. In just a second, I'm going to give focus to the Add Comment button to the right by clicking on it. All of this without keyboard input causing focus.

Comment: If you can't have the focus on a link, it's simply because a link cannot be focused unless you put it on an anchor, or you add a tabindex attribute. But you can focus DOM elements like divs or inputs.

Answer (score -6):

Using "focus" will give keyboard users the same effect that mouse users get when they hover with a mouse. "Active" is needed to get the same effect in Internet Explorer.

The reality is, these states do not work as they should for all users. Not using all three selectors creates accessibility issues for many keyboard-only users who are physically unable to use a mouse. I invite you to take the #nomouse challenge (nomouse dot org).

Comment: :hover and :focus are not the same thing.   :hover is a specific state and :focus is a specific state. It's a little confusing and misleading to equate them.

Comment: I'm not doubting your expertise. I'm trying to point out that :hover and :active are not the same thing. And it's confusing for people newer to web and accessibility when it's put as simply as :hover is approximately equal to :active for keyboard usage. I appreciate the answer, but maybe a little more depth would help?

Comment: Of course they aren't the same thing!  I didn't say they were approximately the same.  (Please read my posts again.)  I'm talking about the difference between using a mouse and using a keyboard to accomplish the same task.  I'm saying you have to use all of them to give both sets of users the same experience.  Otherwise keyboard only users who are physically unable to use a mouse will have difficulty in seeing where they have tabbed to on a page.  This creates an accessibility issue for these folks in navigating the page.