# HTML: how to set link colors only for specific class

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I just saw this question [Don't change link color when a link is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383460/dont-change-link-color-when-a-link-is-clicked) and now I'm stuck.

I have multiple links on my page, some of them with `class="menuLink"`. Now only for those I want to set the colors different as a normal link. If I would just use

```
a:link { color:green}
a:hover { color:red }
...
```

this would apply to all links. But neither

```
.menuLink:link {color:green} 
//I think because the css "doesn't know" that this class is used for links
```

nor

```
.menuLink a:link {color:green}
```

work. How can I achieve this?

Comment: ":link" is the opposite of ":visited" and as such will only select links that *are not visited* http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#link-pseudo-classes

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You were close.

```
a.menuLink:link { color: green; }
```

Was what you intended to achieve. But try this:

```
a.menuLink { color: green; }
```

Would mean a *`a` with a classname of `menuLink`*, the `:link` is redundant.

---

```
.menuLink a:link
```

Would mean *`a` **inside** of an element with a classname of `menuLink`*.

Comment: -1 Adding the "a" in front of the selector shouldn't make any bit of difference, except filtering out elements with the class that are not A elements.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

```
   .menuLink {color: green;}
```

Comment: @Fraggy sorry, you first missunderstood me and now I missunderstood you. The problem wasn't to set the normal color of the link, but the colors of the other states. That's why I posted the link of the other question. But of course it's my fault to pose the question so vague.

Comment: @ValentinoRu no problem, glad you sorted it