# Exam 70-480: CSS order of anchor elements

Tags: html, css

I am currently preparing for the microsoft exam 70-480. In a praxistest I found the following question whose answer I can not explain.

Can someone explain why this is the right answer?

> You are developing a web page by using HTML5 and CSS3.  Hyperlinks on
>   the page must be rendered with a style that reflects the last user
>   action performed.  You need to style the four anchor elements in the
>   document. In what order should you specify the four anchor selectors?

Right Answer:

a:link
a:visited
a:hover
a:active

Comment: There is just a standard rule of the order anchor styles must come in, in order for them to display/work properly -- And that answer is the correct order they must show in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in CSS and HTML5 links can be standardized to follow color coding which helps user to understand which are link is visited and which is not.
technically, A:hover must be placed after the A:link and A:visited rules, since otherwise the cascading rules will hide the 'color' property of the A:hover rule. Similarly, because A:active is placed after A:hover, the active color (lime) will apply when the user both activates and hovers over the A element.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Accepted answer because completely and well explained without referring to external links. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

There are five pseudo-classes for hyperlinks and should you define rules against one or more of these, it is important that you do so in the following order:

```
a:link {}

a:visited {}

a:focus {}

a:hover {}

a:active {}
```

Referencing them in a different order may cause them to cancel each other out. 
One of my favorite mnemonics for remembering this order is (**LVFHA** - **L**ink **V**isited **F**ocus **H**over **A**ctive) is **Let Victoria Free Her Armies**, my least favorite being **LoVe For Hell's Angels**, which I find rather creapy...

Comment: Nice. I personally am a fan of: **L**ord **V**ader's **H**andle **F**ormerly **A**nakin ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383486/2454914))

Answer (score 1):

[From here:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited)
In order to style appropriately links, you need to put the :visited rule after the :link rule but before the other ones, defined in the LVHA-order: :link — :visited — :hover — :active.

Comment: I understand it. Many Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

As it states:

- a: hover MUST come after a: link and a: visited in the CSS definition in order to be effective!
- active MUST come after a: hover in the CSS definition in order to be effective!!

Reference: Meet the Pseudo Class Selectors; CSS Pseudo-classes

http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp