# Relationship between active and focused states

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, css-selectors, pseudo-class

Currently I'm trying to understand how `:active` and `:focus` pseudo-classes related with each other.

Here is my example:

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>

<style>
    a:link    { color: rgb(0, 138, 206);  } /* Blue */
    a:visited { color: rgb(180, 14, 180); } /* Violet */
    a:active  { color: yellow; }
    a:focus   { color: green;  }
</style>
```

If you click on the link, you will see that it's color changed from blue/violet to green. You will not see active state, i.e. yellow.

Then, lets try to remove `a:focus` from our CSS:

```
<style>
    a:link    { color: rgb(0, 138, 206);  } /* Blue */
    a:visited { color: rgb(180, 14, 180); } /* Violet */
    a:active  { color: yellow; }
</style>
```

Now, when we click on the link, it's active state is successfully visible. I.e., the link's color changed from blue/violet to yellow, for a 1 second.

I don't ask about difference between `:active` and `:focus` pseudo-classes - sure, I know it.

My question is about WHY we don't see `:active` state (yellow) in the 1st example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply saying, when you click on the link, both `active` and `focus` states are triggered. For that reason, if you want to see both `active` and `focus` states, `active` must be located below `focus`:

```
<a href="#">
    You will see both active and focus states
</a>

<style>
    a:focus   {
                color: green;
                margin-left: 20px;
    }

    a:active  {
                color: yellow;
                background-color: black;
    }

    /*
    Click on the link, but don't release mouse button.
    You will see, that the link have:
    - yellow text on black background
    - indent

    Then, release mouse button.
    You will see, that the link have:
    - green text
    - indent

    That's fine!
    */
</style>
```

Note, that `active` must be located below `focus`, as I already said. If you try to change the order, you will not see yellow text - it will be always green, because of overwriting `focus` over `active`. Let's show an example:

```
<style>
    /* Incorrect: */

    a:active  {
                color: yellow;
                background-color: black;
    }

    a:focus   {
                color: green;
                margin-left: 20px;
    }
</style>
```

Related question/answer: [What is the difference between :focus and :active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677990/what-is-the-difference-between-focus-and-active) (However, from my point of view, my answer is easier to understand).

**Edit:**

And so, returning to my original example, it was necessary just change the order of `active` and `focus` lines:

```
<a href="#">Test me</a>

<style>
    a:link    { color: rgb(0, 138, 206);  } /* Blue */
    a:visited { color: rgb(180, 14, 180); } /* Violet */
    a:focus   { color: green;  }
    a:active  { color: yellow; }
</style>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't just post this as an answer to the other question? Surely you'd want others looking at that other question to see your take on it, right?

Comment: @BoltClock I think, it will be a bit kludgy, because my answer is closely related to *my* question (instead of "other" question"). From my point of view, it would be better to link it as comment, isn't it?

Comment: Alright, I reread your question and I see where you're coming from now.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between those two examples...

The `:active` state works when you clicked on the element...

...`:focus` works after you clicked the element...

If you see closely, when you click the `<a>`, it becomes `yellow` first and then it will become `green`...

Add some transition delay in the `:focus`...you will know the rest

***Stack Snippet***

```css
a:link {
  color: blue;
}

a:visited {
  color: voilet;
}

a:active {
  color: yellow;
}

a:focus {
  color: green;
  transition: all .3s ease 2s;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

Comment: Interestingly, this doesn't work as you describe in Firefox. It does in Chrome and Edge. I wonder if Firefox just ignores the color: yellow declaration because it sees that a transition to color: green is about to take place (even though the transition is delayed). Naturally, changing color to a different property, like background-color, in either :active or :focus causes it to work as described in all browsers.

Comment: @BoltClock yeah its not working on firefox....even if I remove the `:focus`, `:active` is not working on firefox