# Input field box, remove "background" color

Tags: html, css

This is the image which shows my problem >> https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLJSa.jpg << Here's my html code:

```css
.form-control {
    width: 600px;
    fill: none;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

```html
<form id="contactForm" method="POST" action="">
  <input name="fName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="What should I call you? Person X?" required>
  <br>
  <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Only, if you want to be emailed back">
  <br>
</form>
```

Thank you for reading this ;)

Comment: It looks like there is styling applied when the input element is in a `focus` or `active` state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, it looks like a background is being set when the input is in a certain state. It looks like your using a framework and it is impossible to tell without the code used there, or a codepen/jsfiddle.

The `css` below will set the `background` to `transparent` when the input is in `focus` or `active` states.

```
.form-control:focus, .form-control:active {
    background: transparent;
}
```

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677990/what-is-the-difference-between-focus-and-active)  for information on input states.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution has helped! I'm using Bootstrap(latest version), that's the only framework I'm using. (Or bootstrap isn't a framework, correct me if I'm wrong) Thank you again! :D

Answer (score 0):

In css code instead you can add

```
background-color:transparent;
```

Comment: No it doesn't work, sadly! Although thank you for your time and help :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
form{
  background: #000;
}
.form-control {
    width: 600px;
    fill: none;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}


input:focus {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form id="contactForm" method="POST" action="">
  <input name="fName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="What should I call you? Person X?" required>
  <br>
  <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Only, if you want to be emailed back">
  <br>
</form>
```

Comment: My problem has been fixed, thanks to Anthony, although coming back to your solution, it does not make a difference. Still same error, although thanks.