# Prevent properties defined for :focus from getting applied to :active- CSS

Tags: css

I'm having trouble styling button with `:focus` and `:active` psedo classes.
I have certain properties defined for `:focus` that I dont want to apply for :active.

HTML

```
<button>
  When focused, my bgcolor turns red!<br />
  But  when clicked, where my bgcolor  turns #b0bfc6
</button>
```

CSS:

```
 button { font-weight: normal; color: black; }
  button:focus { 
  background-color: red; 
  text-decoration: underline;
  }
  button:active{
    background-color: #b0bfc6;
    }
```

fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/ph16qjx2/

As you can see in the fiddle, when I click it the button turns to a grey bg, but also takes the property defined for `:focus` (which is `text-decoration: underline; background-color: red`)
how can I prevent the properties defined for `:focus` from getting applied on `:active`

Comment: Check this. what do you asking doesnt make sense https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677990/what-is-the-difference-between-focus-and-active

Comment: I checked it out and it does not help my issue, what I'm trying to say is, when I set some styling on :focus, I dont want it to get applied when I click on the button (:active state). Its in the fiddle you can see...

Comment: Than just simply revert `text-decoration:none` on `:active` state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're looking something like this.

```
 button { font-weight: normal; color: black; }
  button:focus { 
   background-color: red; 
   text-decoration: underline;
  }
  button:active{
    background-color: #b0bfc6;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, actually the issue when I key down, it does not have the underline, but when I'm releasing it changes the bg to red with underline...you can try that here: https://jsfiddle.net/f02brt8v/