# Does :active and :focus gets applied on mouse click? -CSS

Tags: css

I read this article of difference between `:focus` and `:active`,
[What is the difference between :focus and :active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677990/what-is-the-difference-between-focus-and-active)
I understand from this one that when button clicked, the `:focus:active` properties gets applied. However what if when I click, I dont want whatever properties I have defined for `:focus` to be applied on `:active` state 
say I have 3 buttons, and here is CSS:

```
button { color: black; }
  button:focus {   outline: 0;
    text-decoration: underline;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(33, 43, 49, 0.5); }
  button:active {   background-color: #000;
    border-color: #fff;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: none;}
```

now when I click and release the mouse after the click, I want `box-shadow` and `text-decoration` to be none, however it still shows up after releasing the mouse on click, is this the expected behavior of `:focus` and `:active` psedo elements

http://jsfiddle.net/c8txd4e5/

Please can someone enlighten me with the approach?
Thanks

Comment: I am not really sure what is your question? you don't want this to happen or you are not understanding why it's happening?

Comment: I dont wan to get the text underline and box-shadowed when I click and release the mouse, but on focus(when I tab) I want the text to be underline and box-shadow. In my case, the underline and box-shadow is happening in :focus and :active state, even though I have set both properties to none. I dont want this to happen, any suggestions around that?

Comment: the active state last only when the mouse is pressed ... if you release the mouse it's gone and the focus will be kept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's expected. `:active` applies *while the link is being clicked,* i.e. while the mouse button is pressed on it. `:focus` applies *as long as the element is in focus,* which generally lasts from the moment it's first active until you move focus somewhere else on the page with another click elsewhere, a `TAB` key press, etc.

For your example, it sounds like you don't want to put `text-decoration` and `box-shadow` on the `:focus` pseudo-element at all; if you do, as you've noticed, those styles will stay after you release the mouse button, because the link is still in focus, though it's no longer active. So what I think you want is simply to use the `:active` pseudo-element like this:

```
button {
    color: black;
}
button:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
button:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(33, 43, 49, 0.5);
    background-color: #000;
    border-color: #fff;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: I think I was not clear in my questions, sorry about that. I DONT want ```text-decoration``` and ```box-shadow``` on ```:active``` state, but I WANT these both  on ```:focus```, so the issue is when I click on mouse and after releasing it, I dont want to see the underline and box shadow properties. The above solution disables my ```:focus``` which I dont want. I hope this makes sense. thanks

Comment: If you put the `box-shadow` and `text-decoration` in your `:focus` pseudo-element, then it will be there when you release the mouse. That's how that element works. More generally: any styles you don't want after you release the mouse should go into the `:active` pseudo-element. Any styles you *do* want to remain after releasing the mouse should go into `:focus` instead. I hope that makes sense?