# why pressing animation only effect for once?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a button pressing animation using `.div:focus` pseudo-class. But it seems to only work once after the browser is refreshed.

I can't figure out how to make it effective every time when the user presses the button...
Below are the HTML and CSS.

```css
.icon {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
  margin: 15px 0px;
  background-color: #f2f3f7;
  box-shadow: 0.6rem 0.6rem 1.2rem #d2dce9, -0.5em -0.5em 1em #ffffff;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.icon img {
  width: 86%;
  height: 86%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.icon:focus {
  animation: pressbtn 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes pressbtn {
  0% {
    box-shadow: inset 0.6rem 0.6rem 1.2rem #d2dce9, inset -0.5em -0.5em 1em #ffffff;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="icon">
  <img src="https://about.twitter.com/content/dam/about-twitter/en/brand-toolkit/brand-download-img-1.jpg.twimg.1920.jpg">
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`focus` state always keeps until you click outside of that element again, so that's why you cannot trigger `focus` again afterward if you never loose `focus` on the current element.

I'd suggest you use `.icon:active` instead which will apply on every clicks on your expected element.

```css
.icon {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
  margin: 15px 0px;
  background-color: #f2f3f7;
  box-shadow: 0.6rem 0.6rem 1.2rem #d2dce9, -0.5em -0.5em 1em #ffffff;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.icon img {
  width: 86%;
  height: 86%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.icon:active {
  animation: pressbtn 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes pressbtn {
  0% {
    box-shadow: inset 0.6rem 0.6rem 1.2rem #d2dce9, inset -0.5em -0.5em 1em #ffffff;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="icon">
  <img src="https://about.twitter.com/content/dam/about-twitter/en/brand-toolkit/brand-download-img-1.jpg.twimg.1920.jpg">
</a>
```

Comment: this is even ...worse. The box shadow completely disappear after the click. I want the box-shadow to "restore" in 0.2s after user click

Comment: I misunderstood your expectation, so I just modified my answer for your sake of expectation, @Maggie

Comment: If you think it's useful, please mark it as the right answer to your question. That will give me as well as this community a little support. Thank you :D @Maggie

Answer (score 0):

Not use keyframes

```
  .icon:focus {
     box-shadow: none;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` in `.icon:focus` or add it in animation key of `.icon:focus`:

```css
.icon:focus {
  animation: 0.2s ease-in-out 0s infinite pressbtn;
}
```

or

```css
.icon:focus {
  animation: pressbtn 0.2s ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Comment: this is just making the icon box blinking like crazy....

Comment: you can change infinity to any number and you can change 0s to 2s for wait before animation

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `focus`, use `active`. See the differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1678020/17898569). Also, when creating the animation, you need to add the
[`forwards`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp) attribute. But personally, I would go with not setting any animation, instead, directly setting the `box-shadow` property to `none`. This removes the lag that you are seeing.

```css
.icon {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
  margin: 15px 0px;
  background-color: #f2f3f7;
  box-shadow: 0.6rem 0.6rem 1.2rem #d2dce9, -0.5em -0.5em 1em #ffffff;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.icon img {
  width: 86%;
  height: 86%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.icon:active {
  /* animation: pressbtn forwards 0.1s ease-in-out; */
  box-shadow: none;
}

@keyframes pressbtn {
  0% {
    box-shadow: inset 0.6rem 0.6rem 1.2rem #d2dce9, inset -0.5em -0.5em 1em #ffffff;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="icon">
  <img src="https://about.twitter.com/content/dam/about-twitter/en/brand-toolkit/brand-download-img-1.jpg.twimg.1920.jpg">
</a>
```