# how could a <ul> element receive the focus event?

Tags: javascript, html, focus

I'm running the following code to trace the tagName of every control that gets focus in an HTML document:

```
$(function() {
    $("*").bind("focus", function() {
        console.log("tabbed " + this.tagName);
    });
});
```

When this runs I can watch the firebug console and see it trace tags like "A" and "INPUT" which I'd expect to receive focus as I tab through the document.  However it also traces one "UL" tag.  The document has multiple UL tags and only this one UL tag seems to get focus.

Any ideas how this could have happened?  The UL Tag that has focus has no attribute (name, id, etc) so I have no idea how it would have been modified by other script.

(running in firefox.  The page I'm looking at is quite large so I'm not including the source, but the UL tag has no attributes, contains some LIs, one of those LIs does contain a  tag).

According to [Which HTML elements can receive focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus), maybe its because some script has set a tabindex on that UL tag.  I can't find any such script though.

Note that I am not trying to figure out how to make the UL focusable, but rather figure out why it is focusable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Handling focus totally depends on browser implementation.

Hovewer you can force focus on html elements by adding **tabindex** property eg.:

```
<ul tabindex="1">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>

<ul tabindex="2">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

This "hack" should force **UL** elements to be **focusable** (worked for me)

Comment: In this case I don't really want the UL focusable, and am trying to figure out why it is.  It does not have a tabindex property set.  (this is on Firefox, didn't try IE)

Comment: oops, sorry for misleading answer :)

Comment: try removing tabindex with:    $("ul").removeAttr('tabindex');    if this solves problem, then you should recheck included scripts :)

Answer (score 0):

If one of the LIs inside the UL contains an A tag, then the focus event (from the A) might be propagating to the UL.

Comment: focus doesn't propagate (bubble)

Answer (score 0):

From [WHATWG HTML Living Standard § 6.5.2. User interaction – Focus – Data model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#data-model) as of 16 January 2020:

> The term **focusable area** is used to refer to regions of the interface that can become the target of keyboard input. Focusable areas can be elements, parts of elements, or other regions managed by the user agent.
>
> Each [focusable area](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#focusable-area) has a **DOM anchor**, which is a `Node` object that represents the position of the *focusable area* in the DOM. (When the *focusable area* is itself a `Node`, it is its own [DOM anchor](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#dom-anchor).) The *DOM anchor* is used in some APIs as a substitute for the *focusable area* when there is no other DOM object to represent the *focusable area*.
>
> The following table describes what objects can be *focusable areas*. The cells in the left column describe objects that can be *focusable areas*; the cells in the right column describe the *DOM anchors* for those elements. (The cells that span both columns are non-normative examples.)

Specifically, among the obvious cases like explicitly focusable elements, `<area>` and user agent widgets and defaults, the [4<sup>th</sup> row](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#td-fa-4) of [the following table](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#table-fa) is of particular interest:

- **Focusable area**

  > **The scrollable regions of elements that are [being rendered](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#being-rendered) and are not [expressly inert](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#expressly-inert).**
- **DOM anchor**

  > The element for which the box that the scrollable region scrolls was created.
- **Examples**

  > The CSS ['overflow'](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow/#propdef-overflow) property's 'scroll' value typically creates a scrollable region.

Other than a user agent specific behavior, the most plausible explanation is that the `<ul>` element was actually being used as a scrolling container of list items, the items *overflowed* creating a scrollable area, and the user agent (web browser) made provisions so that the scrolling function of the container is accessible in accordance to the HTML standard.

Note that specifying `tabindex="-1"` would suppress it from appearing in the tab navigation order; it would, however, still remain focusable.