# Disabling tab focus on form elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have several `div`s within the same form. What I am trying to do is to disable the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key in one of the `div`s in the form without disabling the tab in the other `div`s in the same form.

**Example Form:**

- div1 - disable <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- div2 - <kbd>Tab</kbd> works
- div3 - <kbd>Tab</kbd> works

Comment: Do you want to disable tab key when the focus is on that div ?

Comment: You mean, that you don't want that the tab key causes the browser to jump into that div?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. yes i am using the lightbox effect.. so i wan the tab key to work only on the top most open div.

Comment: the tab focus starts from top layer and as i keep tabbing it goes on to the bottom layer.. i need the tab to be focussed only on the top div

Comment: @ANIL MANE: A `DIV` can't gain the `focus`.

Comment: @jAndy: But it can! Just add a tabindex to it.

Answer (score 263):

A simple way is to put tabindex="-1" in the field(s) you don't want to be tabbed to.
Eg

```
<input type="text" tabindex="-1" name="f1">
```

Comment: This didn't work for my case of wishing to prevent tabbing into TDs in a TABLE.

Answer (score 17):

Similar to Yipio, I added `notab="notab"` as an attribute to any element I wanted to disable the tab too. My jQuery is then one line.

```
$('input[notab=notab]').on('keydown', function(e){ if (e.keyCode == 9)  e.preventDefault() });
```

Btw, `keypress` doesn't work for many control keys.

Comment: Has anyone tried this? What this does is prevent tabbing *away from* the element, not *to* it.

Comment: @Timwi I just tried it, and it works like a charm. This could in fact be used to solve the OP's question - he would just need to add the `notab="notab"` attribute to every input in his "tab disabled" `<div>`, or update the jQuery selector to target only inputs in that `<div>`.

Answer (score 11):

Building on Terry's simple answer I made this into a basic jQuery function

```
$.prototype.disableTab = function() {
    this.each(function() {
        $(this).attr('tabindex', '-1');
    });
};

$('.unfocusable-element, .another-unfocusable-element').disableTab();
```

Comment: This didn't work for my case: a table with TDs each having a DIV underneath.

Comment: @mikerodent – not all HTML elements can receive focus. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1600194/2927114) to those which can.

Comment: @ - Reggie Pinkham interesting.  Both TD and DIV can, though: please see my answer...

Answer (score 4):

My case may not be typical but what I wanted to do was to have certain columns in a `TABLE` completely "inert": impossible to tab into them, and impossible to select anything in them.  I had found class "unselectable" from other SO answers:

```
.unselectable {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

This actually prevents the user using the mouse to put the focus in the `TD` ... but I couldn't find a way on SO to prevent tabbing into cells. The `TDs` in my `TABLE` actually each has a `DIV` as their sole child, and using `console.log` I found that in fact the `DIVs` would get the focus (without the focus first being obtained by the `TDs`).

My solution involves keeping track of the "previously focused" element (anywhere on the page):

```
window.currFocus = document;
//Catch any bubbling focusin events (focus does not bubble)
$(window).on('focusin', function () {
  window.prevFocus = window.currFocus;
  window.currFocus = document.activeElement;
});
```

I can't really see how you'd get by without a mechanism of this kind... jolly useful for all sorts of purposes ... and of course it'd be simple to transform it into a stack of recently focused elements, if you wanted that...

The simplest answer is then just to do this (to the sole `DIV` child in every newly created `TD`):

```
...
jqNewCellDiv[ 0 ].classList.add( 'unselectable' );
jqNewCellDiv.focus( function() {
    window.prevFocus.focus();
});
```

So far so good. It should be clear that this would work if you just have a `TD` (with no `DIV` child).
Slight issue: this just stops tabbing dead in its tracks. Clearly if the table has any more cells on that row or rows below the most obvious action you'd want is to making tabbing tab to the next non-unselectable cell ... either on the same row or, if there are other rows, on the row below. If it's the very end of the table it gets a bit more tricky: i.e. where should tabbing go then. But all good clean fun.

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable or enable the individual elements. This is how I did it:

```
$(':input').keydown(function(e){
     var allowTab = true; 
     var id = $(this).attr('name');

     // insert your form fields here -- (:'') is required after
     var inputArr = {username:'', email:'', password:'', address:''}

     // allow or disable the fields in inputArr by changing true / false
     if(id in inputArr) allowTab = false; 

     if(e.keyCode==9 && allowTab==false) e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with an input element, I found it useful to set the pointer focus to back itself.

```
$('input').on('keydown', function(e) { 
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
        $(this).focus();
       e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't get it... this prevents tabbing OUT.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.tabDisable').on('keydown', function(e)
{ 
  if (e.keyCode == 9)  
  {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Put .tabDisable to all tab disable DIVs
Like

```
<div class='tabDisable'>First Div</div> <!-- Tab Disable Div -->
<div >Second Div</div> <!-- No Tab Disable Div -->
<div class='tabDisable'>Third Div</div> <!-- Tab Disable Div -->
```