# How to create a CSS class to make input field is readonly

Tags: javascript, css

I want to create a CSS class  to make input field is readonly.

Here is my try:

```
 <style>
 .enableInput input[readonly] {
  color: #CB000F;
 }
</style>
<script>
function changeCss()
{
$("#desg").addClass("enableInput input");
}
</script>
</head>
FirstName:<input type="text" name='fname' id='fname' onBlur="changeCss();">
Designation:<input type="text" name='desg' id='desg' value='Software Engr'>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot use CSS to modify DOM Properties.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to do anything with CSS. there is already a readonly attribute present in html input:

```
<input type="text" name="country" value="Norway" readonly>
```

[See more here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp)

There is no such CSS property which would simply make an input readonly, but in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811045/is-it-possible-to-make-input-fields-read-only-through-css), @James Donnelly gave a workaround to achieve that:

```
.enableInput{
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;          
}
```

Comment: @chaya you can use `pointer-events: none`, but it [lacks support](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the :disabled pseudo class, e.g.

```
input.myClass:disabled {
/* style declaration here */
```

}

Or you can use solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811045/is-it-possible-to-make-input-fields-read-only-through-css)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in jquery only

```
function changeCss()
{ 
$('#desg').prop('disabled', true);
}
```