# How to make a field readonly if it is not null using css in openerp 7?

Tags: css, xml, odoo

I want to make all fields readonly if it has values in openerp 7 without using attrs command. If i use attrs i need to define in all fields.

```css
.openerp .oe_form .oe_form_field_char input,
.openerp .oe_form .oe_form_field_url input,
.openerp .oe_form .oe_form_field_email input,
.openerp .oe_form .oe_form_field_text textarea,
.openerp .oe_form .oe_form_field_selection select {
  width: 10%;
}
```

this is the css code to define width of all fields.I want to use this type of method to acheive my requirements.

Comment: You can not make a field `readonly` with css. You might be able to *hack* it like https://stackoverflow.com/a/16811266/1514875

Comment: Where is the problem defining `attrs` for all fields? If you use `groups` you can define `attrs` in them, too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way with pure css,you must help of jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=text],textarea').each(function(){
       if($(this).val().length > 0)
        $(this).attr('readonly','readonly');
    })

    $('select').each(function(){
       if($(this).val().length > 0)
        $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    })
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=text],textarea').each(function(){
       if($(this).val().length > 0)
        $(this).attr('readonly','readonly');
    })

    $('select').each(function(){
       if($(this).val().length > 0)
        $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Text: <input type="text">
Textarea:<textarea></textarea>
Select:
<select>
   <option></option>
    <option>Ehsan</option>
    <option>Taghdisi</option>
</select>
<br><br><br>
Text: <input type="text" value="Some Text...">
Textarea:<textarea>Some Text...</textarea>
Select:
<select>
    <option>Some Text...</option>
    <option>Taghdisi</option>
</select>
```