# Disable press tab button to next input field in web form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

For example below, user can press tab button on the keyboard to go to next field. Can I disable this function?

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <br><br>
      <select name="gender">
        <option value="M">M</option>
        <option value="F">F</option>
      </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling tab focus on form elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682812/disabling-tab-focus-on-form-elements)

Comment: You can. But you should **not**.

Comment: Like @nnnnnn said, you can. But you shouldn't for ADA users. Read more about that here http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/creating-an-ada-compliant-website/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes use keydown like this :

```
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```