# Is there a way to halt the tab button going any further

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and each page slides over to a new one. I noticed if  user continues to press tab at the end of one div, it jumps into the next hidden dic that should only be viewed if a button is clicked. is there anyway to stop the tab at the last input field?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the hidden div's "tabindex" field to `-1` and remove it when you want it to be shown/able to be tabbed to. More info here: [Disabling tab focus on form elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682812/disabling-tab-focus-on-form-elements)