# How to find focus element on page using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to try this example, but it is doesn't work. Why ?

```
<div id="test"></div>
<script>
    $('#test').focus();
    alert($("*:focus").attr("id"))
</script>
```

Comment: Um, why would you expect to be able to focus on a `div` element?

Comment: it's working for me [js fidle](http://jsfiddle.net/gchoken/Xzp56/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note, as others have mentioned, not all elements can be focussed by default.  You must add the `tabindex` attribute to them to make those elements focussable:

```
<div id="test" tabindex="0"></div>
<script>
    $('#test').focus();
    alert($("*:focus").attr("id"))
</script>
```

When the `tabindex` attribute is applied, your original code works.  See [this working example](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/ywRSE/).

---

In plain JavaScript, `document.activeElement` should return the focussed element, if there is one.  It can also return an element that is active, but not focussed.  The best way to handle it is to check if the element is focussed:

```
function getFocussedElement() {
    var el;
    if ((el = document.activeElement) && el != document.body)
        return el;
    else
        return null;
}
```

It's worth mentioning that this approach should be [*much* faster](http://jsperf.com/focus-pseudo-class-vs-activeelement) than querying with selectors.  Be aware that `activeElement` isn't part of any standard, but it is supported by all major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browser, div's can't accept focus. Change it to an input, and you're good to go.

```
<input  id="test"></input >
<script>
    $('#test').focus();
    alert($("*:focus").attr("id"))
</script>
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus), it all depends on the browser:

> The only standard we have is DOM Level 2 HTML, according to which the
>   only elements that have a focus() method are HTMLInputElement,
>   HTMLSelectElement, HTMLTextAreaElement and HTMLAnchorElement. This
>   notably omits HTMLButtonElement and HTMLAreaElement.

Answer (score 0):

as @lonesomeday said, you can't focus on a `div`

here's an example with an input element instead http://jsfiddle.net/xsp83/

Answer (score 0):

Will this suffice?

```
$("input").focus(function(){
  var f = $(this).attr("id");
  console.log(f);
});
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @SamuelRossille Huh? This is a one year old answer, not a question. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `div` element will be able to gain the focus, from the focus() [docs](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) -

> The focus event is sent to an element when it gains focus. This event
>   is implicitly applicable to a limited set of elements, such as form
>   elements (`<input>`, `<select>`, etc.)