# navigating through tab key not working properly

Tags: java, html, jsp

in my jsp, when i navigate through tab key it skips my Save and Reset button. and move to next component in my page. even though i have not used **tabindex** in my jsp files. please suggest what could be  the reason. thanks

code is like:

```
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey" value="${flowExecutionKey}"/>
<input type="submit" class="button" name="_eventId_search" value="Search"/>
<span class="save_button_common" onClick="submitForm('save')">Save</span>
<span class="reset_button_common" onClick="submitForm('reset')">Reset</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey" value="${flowExecutionKey}"/>
<input type="submit" class="button" name="_eventId_search" value="Search"/>
<input type="button" class="save_button_common" onClick="submitForm('save')">Save</input>
<input type="button" class="reset_button_common" onClick="submitForm('reset')">Reset></input>
</div>
```

Note if it's a form you need input type="button" rather than just using `<button>` which you can otherwise just for straight links that don't submit a form. This is particularly relevant with Internet Explorer that treats the button tag somewhat differently to other browsers (submitting the "value=" rather than the enclosed text or something like that)

Comment: but when i am on this jsp. when i click Enter key the form was getting submitted regardless of component tab key focussing. pls suggest.

Answer (score 1):

May be because it is not `input type` , you can explicitly try setting `tabIndex`

Comment: Elements that can be focused using tab key are `<input>` and `<a>`.

Comment: @AlexR check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus)