# javascript keydown event only work for html input tag?

Tags: javascript, input, keydown

I have used keyDown event to manage the input tag value by judge e.keycode,
but when I want use keyDown event do something on `body` element or `img` ,
I found it doesn't work,like :

```
$('body,img').keyDown(function(e){
    console.log(e.keyCode);
});
```

Does keyDown event only work for `input` tag?

Comment: How do you imaging a keyDown on the `img` element? When is it a keyDown on the `img` and when not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyDown event only works for *focusable* elements. This would include input fields, textareas, etc., but you're probably not going to find any browser support for the `img` element.  From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/):

> The keydown event is sent to an element when the user first presses a
>   key on the keyboard. It can be attached to any element, but the event
>   is only sent to the element that has the focus. Focusable elements can
>   vary between browsers, but form elements can always get focus so are
>   reasonable candidates for this event type.

You may also be interested in this related question:  [Which HTML elements can receive focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus)