# When is an element guaranteed to be focussable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

If a dom element is `:visible`, will it always be focussable?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can't (for instance and by default) focus a div.

Comment: you can if it has a `tabindex`

Comment: @Alnitak — I said "by default".

Answer (score 0):

It's not guaranteed, but you can check to see if an element will fire the `focus` event.

```
var focussableEls = [];
$(":visible").each({
    if (typeof this.focus == 'function')
        focussableEls.push(this.id);
});
console.log(focussableEls);
```

Comment: That appears to come back with html, body and every element in the body, not just those that can be focused. http://jsfiddle.net/TEL4J/

Answer (score 0):

Check for elements that have a `tabindex` attribute:

```
$('[tabindex]')
```

Comment: Elements don't have to have a tabindex attribute to be focusable (e.g. an input element is focusable by default).