# How to focus a p:dataTable single selectable row using JavaScript

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-datatable

PrimeFaces has excellent keyboard support. See for example, the showcase of a [selectable `p:dataTable`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml). When you click a row in the "Single with Row Click" table, you are able to use the arrow keys to navigate rows and use the enter to select the focused row.

I would like to be able to set the focus on a row in a (single) selectable `p:dataTable` using JavaScript.

I checked the [client side API documentation for `DataTable`](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/jsdocs/classes/src_primefaces.primefaces.widget.datatable-1.html) and the [code of the row click handler](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/2c04d80164b8abe54f8377d84bf8e416c1ffb01c/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/datatable/datatable.js#L2261-L2305), and I assume it has something to do with the `originRowIndex` and `cursorIndex` properties. But setting them to `0` (in the JavaScript console) does not trigger a focus. Also, when I focus a row, and then focus the JavaScript console, the focus gets lost, making it hard to figure out what is going on.

Then I checked the [code of the keydown handler](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/2c04d80164b8abe54f8377d84bf8e416c1ffb01c/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/datatable/datatable.js#L882-L901). This made me try the following (again, on the console):

```js
var widget = PF('widget');
row = $('tbody tr', widget.jq).eq(0);
widget.focusedRow = row;
widget.highlightFocusedRow();
row.focus();
```

This will highlight the first row, but the focus is not set. I think I'm close, but stuck with the focus issue.

Comment: How about `widget.getFocusableTbody().trigger('focus')` which should give the focusable TBODY the focus?

Comment: That works, but not from the console. If I use the location bar with `javascript:...` it does work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to focus the focusable TBODY.

```js
widget.getFocusableTbody().trigger('focus');
```

But you will still be facing the issue trying to set focus from the console. See [Unable to set focus and cursor to input text using javascript in Chrome Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29300542/unable-to-set-focus-and-cursor-to-input-text-using-javascript-in-chrome-console/29300935)