# How to put your cursor in the input tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

in [Google](https://google.com), I put the code `document.querySelector('[aria-label="Search"]').select();` How to put your cursor in the input tab in console log to see if the input tab of google gets selected. I confirmed that I correctly called the input tab but the console log just said `undefined` How to put your cursor in the input tab with javascript. If it can't be javascript, please still share how to put your cursor in the input tab

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set cursor to input box in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894638/how-to-set-cursor-to-input-box-in-javascript)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Are you trying to `console.log` the value of an input? Logging `document.querySelector('[aria-label="Search"]').select(); ` should log undefined because it doesn't have a return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have is correct. There are really two parts to your question:

#### Why does the console show `undefined` after running `.select()`?

To make sense of the `undefined`, it's important to understand how the console works. When you enter an expression in the console, it runs it using `eval` and displays the result. For example:

- `1 + 3` evaluates to `4`
- `var a = 1 + 3` evaluates to `undefined`, even though a variable was defined
- `alert("hello")` evaluates to `undefined`, even though an alert was displayed

In your example, `HTMLInputElement.select()` doesn't return anything, so the console simply displays `undefined`. With that being said, the code did in fact run. You can verify this by displaying an `alert` using the console.

(If you're interested in the specifics of how the console decides what to display as the result of an expression, I'd take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22844864/425782).)

#### Why doesn't the search field focus when running `.select()` using the console?

For this part of your question, I'd recommend experimenting with the source of a page you control. Notice that if you setup a button to call `.select()` on a text field, the field will focus. If you run that same code using the console, the field won't focus.

While I'm not sure of the specifics, it seems this is because the developer tools refuse to lose focus without the user specifically clicking a different element or closing them. If you instead wrap your expression in a timeout and change your focus before the timeout executes, your code works as expected.

You can verify this on both your page and Google's by doing the following:

1. Use the console to run:

   ```
   setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('[aria-label="Search"]').select(), 2000)
   ```
2. Quickly click the background of the page to resign focus of the developer tools.
3. Observe that the field focuses when the timeout executes.