# Detect when container and child elements lose focus with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, focus, blur

I wish to determine when an HTML element and it's children lose focus when the user clicks away from the element.  Eg:

```
<div id="boxA">
  <ul>
    <li>x</li>
    <li>y</li>
    <li>z</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="boxB">
...
</div>
```

At the moment I have:

```
$("#boxA").live('blur', function() { hideFunction();  });
```

However, this does not work.  If I click any element within Box A, it loses focus, but I only want it to happen when Box B is clicked or anywhere else on the page.

**Edit & Solution**

I found this solution on Stack Overflow.  It works for me:

[Use jQuery to hide a DIV when the user clicks outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it)

Comment: How can you *click away* from `<div>` element? This is not a form field.

Answer (score 4):

You could try listening on the `focusout` event and then checking if the current element with focus is a child of your container, like this:

```
$('#boxA').on('focusout', function (e) {
    setTimeout(function () { // needed because nothing has focus during 'focusout'
        if ($(':focus').closest('#boxA').length <= 0) {
            hideFunction();
        }
    }, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try giving your div a `tabindex` attribute:

```
<div id="boxA" tabindex="0">
  <ul>
    <li>x</li>
    <li>y</li>
    <li>z</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="boxB" tabindex="1">
...
</div>
```

From the docs:

> In recent browser versions, the [focus] event can be extended to include all
>   element types by explicitly setting the element's tabindex property.
>   An element can gain focus via keyboard commands, such as the Tab key,
>   or by mouse clicks on the element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell me if it worked:

```
$("body").not("#boxA, #boxA ul li").live('focus', function(){ hideFunction(); });
```

Comment: That is not an answer, this should be a comment against the question.

Comment: Why is that? I offering an alternative that has worked for me.

Comment: Your answer makes you sound like you haven't tried it yourself. If you reword it to something like "This worked for me" it's less misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along these lines:

```
$('#boxA, #boxA > *').focusout(function () {
if ($(document.activeElement).closest('#boxA').length == 0){
    alert("not focused");
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AjT9j/3/

Answer (score -1):

As this answer says, any element with a `tabindex` can receive focus, perhaps that's your answer.

[Which HTML elements can receive focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus)