# Detecting for focus in td in table layout

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The task is to take action if the focus is not found on any **td** in a table. The table layout is stored in a **jquery variable**, whose layout looks like this

```
<table class="cal_tbl" cellSpacing="1" cellPadding="3">  <tbody>
<tr>
  <td class="cal_head">&lt;&lt;</td>
  <td class="cal_head">&lt;</td>
  <td class="cal_head" colSpan="3">November 2012</td>
  <td class="cal_head">&gt;</td>
  <td class="cal_head">&gt;&gt;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="cal_subhead">Sun</td>
  <td class="cal_subhead">Mon</td>
  <td class="cal_subhead">Tue</td>
  <td class="cal_subhead">Wed</td>
  <td class="cal_subhead">Thu</td>
  <td class="cal_subhead">Fri</td>
  <td class="cal_subhead">Sat</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colSpan="4"></td>
  <td class="cal_cell">1</td>
  <td class="cal_cell">2</td>
  <td class="cal_cell">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="cal_cell">4</td>
  <td class="cal_cell">5</td>
  <td class="cal_cell">6</td>
  <td class="cal_cell">7</td>
  <td class="cal_cell">8</td>
  <td class="cal_cell">9</td>
  <td class="cal_cell">10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="cal_cell">25</td>
  <td class="cal_cell">26</td>
  <td class="cal_cell">27</td>
  <td class="cal_cell">28</td>
  <td class="cal_cell">29</td>
  <td class="cal_cell">30</td>
</tr>  </tbody></table>
```

I have to check whether the focus is on any of the **td** 
The below is my code what I tried

```
if ($(CurrentCalendarButton).children[i].is(":focus") == true)
     alert("Keep it on")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that all not elements on the DOM actually accept focus, and it's up to the browser to decide which ones do. See [Which HTML elements can receive focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus)

Maybe have a hover event on your **td**:

```
var hasFocus = false;
$('td').hover(
    function () { hasFocus = true;  alert('has focus  !');},
    function () { hasFocus = false; alert('lost focus !');}
);
```