# Detect if cursor is within li on content editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, contenteditable

I have working code that inserts `<br>` when you hit enter in a content editable div. (Browsers have various defaults of inserting `<div>` or `<p>` instead)

The problem is that it kills the default behavior of hitting enter to add another list item when building ordered or unordered lists. So my question is, can you detect if the text insertion point is within a list item, and if so, disable the javascript that deals with the enter key?

Working code: http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/RCdhS/

Comment: Question: Is jQuery available to you? Unsolicited pedantry: You probably either meant "caret" or, more likely, "cursor". EDIT: Never mind. I see that your demo uses jQuery.

Comment: Good call, I updated it to say text insertion point since most people probably think of the "cursor" as the arrow you move with your mouse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to do some DOM tree checking on the node containing the selection. Here's a demo that will work in all major browsers:

http://jsfiddle.net/CeMxs/2/

Code:

```
function isSelectionInsideElement(tagName) {
    var sel, containerNode;
    tagName = tagName.toUpperCase();
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
            containerNode = sel.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
        }
    } else if ( (sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control" ) {
        containerNode = sel.createRange().parentElement();
    }
    while (containerNode) {
        if (containerNode.nodeType == 1 && containerNode.tagName == tagName) {
            return true;
        }
        containerNode = containerNode.parentNode;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you. Looks good! I will check it out further and accept the answer if it works out.

Comment: This does detect if you're inside an <li>. +1 for that! However, I can't get this to work with the existing code in my question above.

Comment: Note that this does not work using Chromium v30.0.1599.114 on Xubuntu. In the fiddle, the `alert` dialog prevents the return false from preventing the event to bubble. Removing the `alert` statement resolves the issue.

Comment: @DaveJarvis: Good point. I've added an updated jsFiddle. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/RCdhS/2/

```
.on('keypress', 'document', function (e) {
    if (!$('li').focus();) {
    ...
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't seem that an li can have focus

Comment: You're right, though you might be able to get around that by applying tabindex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus

Comment: I've updated my answer to use on() rather than live(), though it's untested. The latter has been deprecated for some time and has been removed as of jQuery 1.9.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it further. I've added some tab indexes to the list items, and updated the code to display an alert if you hit enter while focused on the <li>. I can't get it to function though. http://jsfiddle.net/RCdhS/3/