# How do I simulate hover with Javascript on keydown?

Tags: javascript, hover, onkeydown

First of, I'd like to use only native JavaScript to complete this task.

Let's say I am to make a custom dropdown, and the HTML code looks kind of like this.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <span class="dropdown-label" style="display:block">Select a thing</span>
  <ul class="dropdownItemContainer">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In the CSS file I have something close to this:

```
ul.dropdownItemContainer li:hover {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Yeah, there's really no dropdownish behavior, but it's not the point of discussion actually. The problem is that I couldn't think of a decent way to enable keyboard control for this dropdown. The desired outcome is the following: I press the down key, and the first option is highlighted; I press it again, and the second option is highlighted and so on.

The only option that I see at this point (just started studying JS) is to fetch all of the `ul`'s children, stick'em into an array and assign the tags a background color through JS methods in a proper way whenever the down key is pressed.

On the other hand, I still have the :hover behavior described in the CSS for mouse countrol. Is there a smart way of simulating hovers?

Comment: Keyboard navigation makes heavy use of `:focus`.

Comment: @AlessandroVendruscolo true, but I can't really get a focus on anything onther than <a href="something"> or regular control elements, can I? :)

Comment: only jQuery solutions come to my mind :(

Comment: Add the `tabindex` attribute, or put anchors inside the `li`s — see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1600194/799073)

Comment: @AlessandroVendruscolo focus events on base of tabindex are not very reliable. E.g. the `:focus` pseudoclass won't trigger in some browsers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would go with a simple assignment of a class on your li-elements and steer it with a keydown handler. The following code is not meant to be complete but give you something you can work with.

```
var active = document.querySelector(".hover") || document.querySelector(".dropdownItemContainer li");

document.addEventListener("keydown",handler);
document.addEventListener("mouseover",handler);

function handler(e){
    console.log(e.which);
        active.classList.remove("hover");
    if (e.which == 40){
        active = active.nextElementSibling || active;
    }else if (e.which == 38){      
        active = active.previousElementSibling || active;
    }else{
        active = e.target;
    }
        active.classList.add("hover");
}
```

You can see a **[working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/GSNgf/1/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution, I was struggling with the same problem for quite a lot time.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a library instead of coding this from scratch.

http://vebersol.net/demos/jquery-custom-forms/

http://www.dreamcss.com/2009/05/15-jquery-plugins-to-enhance-your-html.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but, as I've mentioned, I'm trying to study native JS, so I actually want to code this whole thing from scratch. I know that JQuery provides a lot of possibilities and customization options, and I admit they're cool and useful, but I'll get to it eventually :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Hd7X9/ - here you go. I've written you on facebook, guess I'll need to give you some more background.

Answer (score 0):

Reality you didn't need any js for dropdown but You can use JavaScript Event for simulating  it. You can use event like **hover**, **focus**, **onclick**

In JS You Can use This For Set Event

```
  document.getElementById('id').addEventListener('focus',function(e){
    //place code that want ran at event happened
  }
```

In JQuery you can use **bind**, **click** ,...

```
  $('#id')bind('focus',function(e){
    //place code that want ran at event happened
  }
```

List of Event

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html

Comment: @Christoph Yes we can use focus event  http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html

Comment: well, the fact that the focus element is supported does not change the fact that only `window`, links and formfields can be focussed by default. You need to declare `tabindex` on an element otherwise, and even then, focus is inconsistently supported.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing the hover attribute from css. 
And add only a hovered class which is applied on keypresses and on mouseover

This could look like this in Code

```
var dropDown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdownItemContainer")[0]

document.addEventListener("keydown",function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 40 ) {
        var key = e.keyCode
        var hovered = dropDown.getElementsByClassName("hovered")
        if(hovered.length != 0 ) {
            cur = hovered[0]
            cur.className = ""
            cur = cur[(key==38?"previous":"next")+"ElementSibling"] || dropDown.children[key==38?dropDown.children.length-1:0] 
        } else {
            cur = dropDown.children[key==38?dropDown.children.length-1:0]
        }
        cur.className="hovered"
    }
});


dropDown.addEventListener("mouseover",function (e) {
    for( var i = 0,j; j = dropDown.getElementsByClassName("hovered")[i];i++)
        j.className = "";
    e.srcElement.className = "hovered";
});
```

Heres an example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rTjbU/)