# Select checkbox of gridview with keyboard in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using `GridView` on my page, which retrieves data from SQL database.

The first column is named `OK` and has a Checkbox in each row.

I want to select each check box with the help of keyboard instead of mouse.

Comment: You can press `Tab` repeatedly until you hit a checkbox, then `space`. Rinse an repeat

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut for toggling a checkbox is the spacebar, so as long as you have the checkbox highlighted, you can use that to check each box.

Next, check out some articles on adding GridView keyboard navigation:

- [GridView column and row navigation using up/down/right and left arrows](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/110180/GridView-column-and-row-navigation-using-up-down-r)
- [GridView Rows Navigation Using Arrow (Up/Down) Keys](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25675/GridView-Rows-Navigation-Using-Arrow-Up-Down-Keys)
- [GridView Up and Down Navigation using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15020095/1366033)