# Select all children on focus

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want a selector for all children of an element on focus

I've tried the following and it didn't work

```css
#myElement > * :focus { /*stuff*/}
```

Comment: You mean `#myElement:focus > * { /*stuff*/ }`?

Comment: @j08691 I'm customizing meganizr mega-menu. I want a certain drop-down to keep showing if there's any child on focus. For that, I want to add in the list of selectors to set the visibility of the dropdown this one I've described.

Comment: @Torr3nt I'm using actually. Instead of #myElement I'm using .myClass. Simplified it just for the question.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand what you're asking. If you're trying to change a parent's CSS based on a child, you won't have any luck. CSS is quite literally Cascading. It goes in a downward motion, and can't go back up in the hierarchy.

Comment: @Torr3nt: You'll be surprised to know that that's not actually what "cascading" means in terms of CSS. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

focus only works with elements that accept keyboard input. try toggling a class from javascript based on events like "Focus" and "blur"

Comment: This isn't true, `:focus` works on `<a>` elements and that doesn't accept keyboard input. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus

Comment: @rink.attendant.6, read the manual: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes. It clearly states that <a> elements or others are implementation specific, and not cross browser.

Comment: You're linking to an old CSS specification. See [Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act)

Comment: yes, you're right, but still it's not safe to use for all children of an element.

Comment: My solution ended up using javascript and JQuery selectors... thank you!