# Is that possible to use "hasFocus" on divs in KnockoutJS?

Tags: knockout.js

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/liyem/1/edit)

Buttons are built as `div`s.

I would like to create the following behavior:

- When user clicks on the button, a dialog appears.
- Then, if user clicks anywhere else on the page, the dialog disappears.

I'm struggling to implement the second requirement.

[I tried](http://jsbin.com/liyem/1/edit) to use [`hasFocus`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html) on `div`s, but it doesn't seem to work. Looks like `hasFocus` works on input elements like `input`, `button`, etc.

How would you implement the desired behavior?

Comment: Be ware of browser support for `div`s being able to take focus ([this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1599660/419956) seems to talk about that).

Comment: Think you can simplify this a little. Put a click binding on a div (button) and click binding on the main container. And you disable bubble clicking, and you have it. If you need an example let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I found is to put `tabindex` on the `div`. This makes the `div` focusable.

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/dahezule/1/edit)