# keydown and keypress events not working in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive where I am trying to bind the keypress and keydown events but for some reason they will not register.

```
element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
    console.log("here");
});
```

Any clues why this could be ?

If you look at the file `selectMe.js` in this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hahh4uyQ130zOS8noC3D) you can see the binding.

Comment: Where is that directive in your template?

Comment: sorry..i was debugging it..trying various events.. put it back in.. please check the file selectMe.js

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the built in key directives? http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress. Also what are you trying to bind? don't you need something to have focus to get key events?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `tabindex="0"` to the `<table>`. With this you make the `<table>` focusable with a click or pressing `tab`. However you may be interested on starting listening to key events as soon as the page is loaded. Then you should bind the event to `document`:

```
angular.element(document).bind(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you bind to the table element, you won't get key events because the table doesn't have focus.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus) for info on which elements can have focus.

The events do bubble up however, so you can either add an invisible input or anchor element and get the keyboard events when they bubble up, or just listen on your document element to get any unhandled events.  You can also check the `ctrlKey` flag on the key event instead of tracking the control key yourself:

```
var doc = angular.element(document);
doc.on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey) {
    if (e.keyCode === cKey) {
        $scope.valueToBeCopied = e.target.value;
        console.log('copy: valueToBeCopied: ' + $scope.valueToBeCopied);
      }
      if (e.keyCode === vKey) {
        e.target.value = $scope.valueToBeCopied;
        console.log('paste: valueToBeCopied: ' + $scope.valueToBeCopied);
      }
    }
});
```

I don't know how much that helps though with what you seem to be attempting.  You'll have to track which element has the virtual 'focus' some other way.

Comment: Jason.. doesn't quiet work.. this simply gives me all the cells in the table and not the one i clicked on.. you can see a plnkr here    http://plnkr.co/edit/0NuKiaKYxmDl2NVSTaDJ       goto file ctMyCell.js

Comment: I don't see where you are selecting a row, that is what my last statement was about.  You'll have to do something to mark a row as selected, i.e. add a 'selected' class to the table row or add a selected property to the scope or row object.  I don't think your question has enough detail about what you are trying to do for me to help any more.  You should write another question with more details since I think this one is limited enough to be useful on its own.