# Blur event not works for div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code below I'm trying to hide addstuff id div when clicked out of it. I tried body click event but it was useless. So I need a trigger event like blur. But It doesn't work for both blur and focusout events.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#addstuff').blur(function () { $('#addstuff').fadeOut() })
 })
```

Comment: `#addstuff` is a div?

Comment: there's no `blur` (or `focus`) event for a div

Comment: ...and the reason divs do not have `blur` and `focus` is that "focus" relates to the current editing position (i.e. keyboard focused controls), so can normally only apply to input-type elements (HTML 5 does allow focus on non-input elements, but that is not portable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no blur event for div. You can create that effect using the click event of body.Note that you should exclude that div from the click event

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").not("#addstuff").click(function (e) {
        $("#addstuff").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2uus5/1/)

**Edit**

As @TrueBlueAussie suggested, it would be better to use `document` instead of `'body'` for the click event handler:

```
   $(document).not("#addstuff").click(function (e) {
       $("#addstuff").fadeOut();
   });
```

Comment: You might want to attach click to `document` and not `'body'` as `body` can have weird side-effects with click (absolute position elements can cause a zero-height body that does not accept clicks on some browsers)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Thanks for the suggetion. I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

There's no way you can use .blur with a div, it has to be with some input field.

You can always use mouse events like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#addstuff").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/asrF2/

You can also use the HTML5 global attribute `contenteditable` (don't forget to set it true or false)

```
<div id="#addstuf" contenteditable="true">bla bla</div>
```

I don't recommend this that much, because of mobile browsers' compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

divs have no focus and blur events, but you can add a contenteditable attribute so that you can type in that div, so the blur actually gets fired:

```
<div id="addstuff" contenteditable></div>
```

Then your jquery code [works](http://jsfiddle.net/2uus5/).

You can add additional functions to prevent people from actually typing in that div.

Alternatively you can use the `.mouseleave()` or `.mouseout()` event.

Comment: *Note: `contenteditable` is a HTML5 feature, so may not work on older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

div element cannot be focused on so the blur function of jquery cannot be applied to it. See existing answers from our Stack Exchange buddies below for elements that focus can be applied on.

[Which HTML elements can receive focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus)