# How to call onkeydown/onfocus to a list tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list, and within this list im trying to call a function when keyisdown/onfocus/etc? This wont trigger the function:

```
 <li onkeydown="myFunction()"></li>
```

The normal onclick works fine(calling the function when the "click is going up") and will trigger the function:

```
<li onclick="andrafarg()"></li>
```

So my question is: How can i call this function when the list is clicked immediately down?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the jQuery docs:

> The keydown event is sent to an element when the user first presses a
>   key on the keyboard. It can be attached to any element, but the event
>   is only sent to the element that has the focus. Focusable elements can
>   vary between browsers, but form elements can always get focus so are
>   reasonable candidates for this event type.

So as `li` elements can't get focused, the `keydown`-event will never be triggered.
For a reference for focusable elements, you might have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1600194/4202224) answer.

**But** because of the [event-bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616694/4202224), an `input`-field inside the list will trigger the `keydown`-event, if the event-listener is registered on the input itself or a parent-element.
Example:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="text" /></li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('ul > li').on('keydown', function(){
   alert('Event triggered'); 
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nskg9dqm/)

Comment: @mattias as they can recieve focus, the button-element itself will trigger an keydown event, yes.

Comment: On one project, I added tabindex="0" to all li elements (zero for all), it makes them focusable (<li tabindex="0">...)