# How do I listen for keyPress event on list elements in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, keypress

I have tried this way but it doesn't work. It doesn't even log a simple text in the console. How do I listen for a keyPress event on the list element?

```
<MotionUL variants={dropUlAnimVariant}>
                  {category.map((item, i, arr) => {
                    return (
                      <MotionLI
                        key={i}
                        className={`cursor-pointer list-none ${
                          i === state.selectIndex
                            ? 'text-white'
                            : 'text-gray-400'
                        }  hover:text-white ${
                          item === arr.slice(-1).join('')
                            ? 'border-none'
                            : 'border-b border-[#2d2d2d]'
                        } py-2`}
                        role="button"
                        ariaPressed={i === state.selectIndex}
                        tabIndex={0}
                        onClick={() => {
                          setCurrentCatItem(item);
                          dispatch({ type: 'select', payload: i });
                        }}
                        onKeyPress={(e) => {
                          console.log(item); //NOT WORKING
                        }}
                      >
                        {item}
                      </MotionLI>
                    );
                  })}
                </MotionUL>
```

Motion.LI is a component that returns an element from the framer motion library called motion.li. It's just a parent component that wrapped up its children.

Motion.LI.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { dropdownLiAnimVariant } from '../assets/constants';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
const MotionLI = ({
  children,
  className,
  onClick,
  key,
  role,
  ariaPressed,
  tabIndex,
  onKeyPress,
}) => {
  return (
    <motion.li
      className={className}
      onClick={onClick}
      variants={dropdownLiAnimVariant}
      whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
      key={key}
      role={role}
      aria-pressed={ariaPressed}
      tabIndex={tabIndex}
      onKeyPress={onKeyPress}
    >
      {children}
    </motion.li>
  );
};

export default MotionLI;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what this component MotionLI is all about or do you have some snippet for the same.

Comment: Motion.Li is a component that returns an element from the framer motion library called motion.li. It's just a parent component that wrapped up its children.

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069639/listen-to-keypress-for-document-in-reactjs#answer-57926311

Comment: I think you need to create a ref() and then from that you can set an event listener.

Comment: okay, I will try.

Comment: Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30126427/how-to-call-onkeydown-onfocus-to-a-list-tag. As li tag can't get focused we can't listen onKeyPress. Another thing is that the method is deprecated so better use it's alternative: onKeyDown

Comment: useRef() is the solution. thanks everyone.