# Angular directive : bind keydown to anchor element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the following directive :

```
.directive('hasFocus',function(){
   return{
      restrict: 'A',
      link : function(scope,element,attrs){
           element.on('keydown',function(e){    
                switch(e.which){
                        case 38 : 
                            e.preventDefault(); 
                            selectNextButton($(this),true);
                        break;
                        case 40 : 
                            e.preventDefault(); 
                            selectNextButton($(this));
                        break;
                    }
                });
       }
   }
});
```

---

This works fine when I attach it to a button, but does not work when I attach to an anchor.

```
<button id="mybutton" has-focus>the button</button>


<a id="mybutton" data-ng-click="doSomething()" has-focus>the anchor</a>
```

---

I want to be able to capture **e.which** when the user is navigating using the directional arrows.

Is it not possible to bind a keydown event to an anchor ?

---

https://api.jquery.com/keydown/ states that it can :

"**The keydown event is sent to an element when the user first presses a key on the keyboard. It can be attached to any element, but the event is only sent to the element that has the focus**."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem like you can not set focus for `anchor` tag **on click** when there is **no exist** `href` attributes in your `anchor`. Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus#answer-1600194) on stackoverflow which consists a list of `DOM element` that is able to receive `focus`. What you can do is to add in `href` attributes to `anchor` and it should work based on your expectation. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/h50rjkna/).