# javascript - child element can't focus

Tags: javascript

I want to dynamically insert childnode in cursor position and set focus

```
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var selectionContents = range.extractContents();
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.id= 'ttt';
span.style.color = "red";
span.appendChild(selectionContents);
span.innerText = 'dfdf';
range.insertNode(span);
```

i can set node focus, but chileNode can't

```
dom.focus();//OK
dom.lastElementChild.focus();//can't
```

log lastElementChild  i can see  the span and id='ttt'.....

Comment: I believe span does not have a focus property.

Comment: really?  how can i do

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location.hash = '#ttt';`

This will scroll to the element

Answer (score 0):

As I have already commented, `span` does not have focus event. Following is a [SO Post - Which HTML elements can receive focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus) for reference.

To answer your question, you can try adding a textbox with `readonly` property and add proper css to mimic it as label.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/dcrzdrc5/2/)

#### Edit 1

I have added css in `:focus`. You should create a class and toggle this class.

#### Code

```js
function focusDiv() {
  document.getElementById("divTT").focus();
}

function focusSpan() {
  document.getElementById("lblTT").focus();
}

function focusText() {
  document.getElementById("txtTT").focus();
}
```

```css
div:focus{
  background:blue;
}
span:focus{
  background:blue;
}
input:focus{
  background:blue;
  font-size:20px;
  font-family:Gorgia;
  color:#eee;
}

.label{
  border:0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">Test
  <br/>
  <span id="lblTT">Span</span>
  <br/>
  <div id="divTT">Div</div>
  <input type="text" id="txtTT" class="label" value="Text" readonly>
</div>
<button onclick="focusSpan()">Focus Span</button>
<button onclick="focusDiv()">Focus Div</button>
<button onclick="focusText()">Focus Text</button>
```

Comment: Thank you!!  but i want add a span or div or font when i click some button 
`<div>dddddd </div>` => `<div>dddddd <font fontSize color .....></font></div>`
then set focus in font  , when user continued input after click button , input will change font size and color  
, what can I do? thanks