# jQuery: react upon focusing a <select>'s <option>?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that I can react upon focusing an element by `.focus` in jQuery. This seems to work for most elements, but it doesn't for an `<option>` element. I hoped that, when browsing through a `<select>` element with the up/down keys, I could fire a `.focus` event for each `<option>`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Is this normal behaviour? Is there a workaround? I have created a demo:

http://codepen.io/jmuheim/pen/ONmmqr

My intention is to create a custom `<select>` element that looks very fancy using `<div>`s, but in the background it's just a plain ol' visually hidden `<select>` element, and the fancy `<div>`s are simply shown and hidden depending on the `<select>`'s state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it using <s>keydown</s> change event.
this covers both keyboard and mouse click changes

```
<select id="options" size="2">
  <option>option 1</option>
  <option>option 2</option>
</select>
```

jquery:

```
$("#options").on("change", function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: have you tested it? I did similar stuff and it didnt work

Comment: Perfect, thank you! So the `size` attribute is the real game changer here.

Comment: One last question: instead of accessing the value as string, how can I access the actual `<option>` element in jQuery?

Comment: Ah I see, simply with `$(@).find('option:selected')`! ;)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus), the option elements themselves do not possess the `focus()` method, however `<select>` does, and it works in your code as it's supposed to. Using `onmouseover()` may help you implement similar behavior.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you miss something in your sentence `however does, and it works in your code as it's supposed to`? What "however does"?