# Set focus on dataTable in javascript

Tags: javascript, setfocus

```
<table id="table-dispatch" class="display data-table" cellspacing="0" width="100%"  onclick="showrequestmap()">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th> ID </th>
            <th> Status </th>
            <th> Client </th>
            <th> Client Phone Number </th>
            <th> Dispatch Date </th>
            <th> Driver </th>
            <th> Distance </th>
            <th> Current Location </th>
            <th> Estimated Fare </th>
            <th> Action </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td> Waiting for pickup </td>
            <td> Raj </td>
            <td> 85115 </td>
            <td> Apr 18, 2016 7:07 PM </td>
            <td> tushar patel </td>
            <td> NaN </td>
            <td> Thaltej, Ahmedabad, Gujarat 380054, India </td>
            <td> 0$ </td>
            <td> action </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

this is my DataTable. And how to set focus method on DataTable in JavaScript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#table-dispatch").focus(function() {  
  });
});
```

this is my JavaScript code.i try focus method on DataTable Id. But it does not work. so how can i focus method use on DataTable. please give me solution.
And how give first priority to focus method before on-click Method.

Comment: seems like table element cannot have focus

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus/#answer-1600194

Comment: can i use hover on DataTable.

Comment: you can animate your table with borders, so finally you are achieving functionality like focus..

Comment: sir please can you write code.i do not  understand.

Comment: is it ok if i use jQuery

Comment: i also use jQuery. but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just look at these code, it's not hover, but i achieve the same functionality by mouseover() function.

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/eua98tqa/12/

jQuery:

```
$('#table-dispatch').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).css('background-color','#ddd');
}).mouseout(function(){
  $(this).css('background-color','#bbb');
});
```

Comment: Akhil, if it works then please upvote and mark my answer, this will really helps me..