# Simplest way to make the element getting clicked being focused?

Tags: javascript, html

There are lots of methods allowing one element getting click and another element getting focused but using them on making the element itself getting focused seems to be a waste of resource.

I tried

```
<div onclick="this.focus()"></div>
```

and

```
<div onclick="this:focus"></div>
```

and it didn't seem to work.

No jquery please, and don't capture all the clicks. It's an overkill for resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the tabindex of the div to 0 in order to allow it to be focused by the user:

```
<style>
div:focus {
   background-color:yellow;
}
</style>

<div tabindex="0" onclick="this.focus();">CLICK HERE to Focus</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus):

*If you call HTMLElement.focus() from a mousedown event handler, you must call event.preventDefault() to keep the focus from leaving the HTMLElement.*

Also note that not all HTML elements can receive focus.  (See [this SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus).)

Ted's idea of scrolling to it using an anchor is a good one.