# How do I capture a keypress when focus is on my styled DIV?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, keypress

I’m using jQuery 1.12.  I have a couple of styled select menus on my page.  When one is active, I would like to be able to press “Tab” and then have focus shift to the next styled select menu.  I’m trying this

```
return $('div.select-styled:first').keydown(function(e) {
  alert("key pressed");
  if (e.which === 9) {
    $('div.select-styled.active').each(function() {
      return $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide();
    });
    return $('div.select-styled:second').focus().click();
  }
});
```

but nothing’s happening.  You can see from my Fiddle — http://jsfiddle.net/cwzjL2uw/5/ , that you can click “Tab” on the last name field and the first styled select menu is activated, but then clicking “Tab” a second time does nothing.  How do I capture the keypress event from my styled select menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The styled select element is implemented via an div element, which cannot get focus unless is has a `tabindex` attribute. You can set the `tabindex` to `-1` if you want an element to become focusable.

For your code, the `wrapper` can be set to following:

```
var $wrapper = $("<div />", {
  'class': "select",
  'tabindex': '-1'
})
```

Then your code may work as your expectation.

However, the tab focus is already a basic functionality that borwser provides, which means that instead of listening to the tab key event, you should listen 
to `focus` and `blur` event and update the representation of your control. In this case, you should set the `tabindex` to `1`, and add event handler.
Then you can remove the `keydown` event listener as well as the listener on `body` to detect the lost of focus.

Here is the updated fiddle you can check:
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwzjL2uw/8/)

See also:

- [Which HTML elements can receive focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus)
- [Some best practice about `tabindex`](http://adrianroselli.com/2014/11/dont-use-tabindex-greater-than-0.html)

Comment: Besides, you need to use `nth-child(2)` to select the second `select` element instead of `second`.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Although it works great on Chrome (I can tab from one menu to the next), on Firefox I can't tab from one menu to the next.  Is tehre a way to make this code cross-browser -- at least have it work on both Chroem and Firefox?

Comment: Updated the code ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwzjL2uw/8/)) and set the `tabindex` of both `input` and styled `select` to `1`. Thus firefox will iterate the focus in these elements.