# Why isn't my DIV capturing keypress events when it has the focus?

Tags: jquery, html, events, focus, keypress

I’m using jQuery 1.12.  I want a DIV to capture key presses (specifically, down nd up arrows), when it has the focus.  So I followed this

```
 $('div.select-styled').bind('keydown', function(event) {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
    elt = $(this).search(".select-options li:hover");
    console.log(elt);
    switch(event.keyCode){
    // case up
    case 38:
        console.log(“up pressed.”)
        break;
    case 40:
        console.log(“down pressed”)
        break;
    }
 });
```

but this is not capturing the key presses.  See my Fiddle here — http://jsfiddle.net/cwzjL2uw/10/ .  Click on the “Select State” menu, or click on the “Last Name” field and click “Tab” to give focus to the next DIV.  However, when that menu has focus, clicking on any key doesn’t activate the handler above, at least it didn’t for me on Mac Chrome or Firefox.

Grateful for any help, -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, when you press `tab`, the focus is on `.select` instead of `.select-styled` `div element`, since `.select` is the parent which holds the rest of the elements within. So you probably might need to bind your `keydown` onto `.select`.

```
$(".select").on('keydown',function(event) {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
    elt = $(this).search(".select-options li:hover");
    console.log(elt);
    switch(event.keyCode){
    // case up
    case 38:

        break;
    case 40:
        break;
    }
});
```

Here's the **[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/cwzjL2uw/12/)**

Comment: This only works because the `.select` element already has the `tabindex` attribute (per my answer below) - but not just because `.select` is the parent. Remove `tabindex` and you'll see the issue come back.

Comment: I noticed that and that is why it is receiving focus. I wanted to let OP know that the binding ain't gonna work on `div.select-styled` as it has not focus. So my suggestion is to bind on `.select` element. @JonUleis

Answer (score 2):

Giving your `.select-styled` element the `tabindex` attribute (ex: `tabindex="1"`) will allow it to receive JavaScript keyboard events.

---

**Explanation:** 
The jQuery API for [`.keydown()`](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/) mentions that it only works on focusable elements:

> It can be attached to any element, but the event is only sent to the
>   element that has the focus. Focusable elements can vary between
>   browsers, but form elements can always get focus so are reasonable
>   candidates for this event type.

Per this [previous Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus), `<div>` elements are not focusable by default, but [DOM Level 2 HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html) states that among other rules, any element with a `tabindex` can receive focus:

> Today's browsers define focus() on HTMLElement, but an element won't
>   actually take focus unless it's one of:
>
> - HTMLAnchorElement/HTMLAreaElement with an href
> - HTMLInputElement/HTMLSelectElement/HTMLTextAreaElement/HTMLButtonElement
>     but not with disabled (IE actually gives you an error if you try),
>     and file uploads have unusual behaviour for security reasons
> - HTMLIFrameElement (though focusing it doesn't do anything useful).
>     Other embedding elements also, maybe, I haven't tested them all.
> - Any element with a tabindex

---

**Alternatively**, and this might be better practice, you could simply bind your `keydown` event handler to the `$(document)` when the element receives `focus` (which your jQuery already handles without an issue), and unbind it on `blur`.