# Why is it impossible to effect child element with focus?

Tags: css

I was thinking that there's only two ways to focus element - using JavaScript, or in case it's a `div` with an `contenteditable` attribute. But this time I tried something different: I tried to effect `input[type="text"]` within a div (without `contenteditable`) using the parent.

I know that when a child element is focused, the parent is focused too - I mean, If I have the following example:

```
<form action="/" method="get">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Hi I'm Text!" />
</form>
```

When I focus on the textbox, the form will be focused too. I can do the following:

```
form input[type="text"]:focus {
    /* CSS goes here */
}
```

But **I can not** do something like this:

```
form:focus > input[type="text"] {
    /* The same CSS goes here */
}
```

I already solved my own problem, but I wonder why it can not work this way. As I said (and feel free to correct me if I'm wrong) - when I focus on the input, I'm automatically focusing the parent element too (and it's own parent element, etc.) So why can't I simply use `:focus` on the parent, and then effect the child?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which HTML elements can receive focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't focus on a `form` element. If you want, you can add it the `tabindex` attribute, such as `<form tabindex="0">`.

Comment: I know I can't... I asked why is it impossible.

Comment: Becuase only some of the elements can be focused, depend on the browser you use. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1600194/63409650) explains it.

Comment: Glad I could help, Bevakasha!

Answer (score 0):

Forms are containers for controls and as such not expected to be getting direct user interaction.

According to W3C, users should interact with forms using controls.

Reference:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-controls