# Trigger Delete on Keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, performance

The code snippet provided will Pop Up Alert when Backspace and Delete Key is Pressed on Keyboard with the cursor clicked on the textbox. However, now I want to implement it in my codepen demo [here](https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/gOdzBqg), but I am unsure on how to do it. **I want the alert box to pop up only when the cursor is placed on the grey box only if the Backspace and Delete Key is Pressed.** I will really appreciate any help I can get.

```html
Click on Text Box and Press on Delete and Backspace for Pop UP
<br>
<input id="input">

<script>
var myinput = document.getElementById('main-container');
input.onkeydown = function() {
  if (event.keyCode == 8) {
    alert('you pressed backspace');
    //event.preventDefault();
  }

  if (event.keyCode == 46) {
    alert('you pressed delete');
    //event.preventDefault();
  }
};

</script>
```

I have tried `var myinput = document.getElementById('zoomPanCont');` , which is the div id but it does not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but does [stackoverflow.com/a/48868196](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48868196) answer your question? You just need to add the `tabindex` attribute to the div

Comment: Hi, thank you for your link. I have copied an example from the link to be tested out at https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/xxajQZb?editors=1011, but it uses 'keydown', which means any key can trigger it, may I ask how do I do with just the delete key and not any other key to trigger it? Thank you :)

Comment: So, I believe I must assign it by ClassName and Not ID right for it to work?

Comment: @Jimmy Brown No, the issue was that the div element isn't selectable. Add `tabindex="0"` to the div and then your original code should work