# How to make CSS transition work with focus instead of hover?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple CSS transition which increases the size of an element on hover. I would like to do the same but on focus, because the UI will be controlled through keyboard only. How can I do that? If I change `:hover` to `:focus` it does not work.

```css
  .card {
         height: 200px;
         width: 140px;
        /* margin: 20px;*/
         overflow: hidden;
         transition: box-shadow 0.15s ease-out, transform 0.25s ease;
         perspective: 600px;
         border-radius: 5px;
        
    }
     .card:hover {
         transform: scale(1.1);
         box-shadow: none;
    }
     .card.hover--ending {
         transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease;
    }
```

```html
    <a href="/hello">
      <article class="card">
         <image type="image" src="https://icdn6.digitaltrends.com/image/google_1998-316x95.jpg" class="card__image posterImage focusable" />
      </article>
    </a>
```

Comment: What is supposed to get the focus here?

Comment: The href. The client will use the keyboard(i.e. tab ). The scope is to create an UI navigable using the keyboard and provide some transition effects to emphasize the focused element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You focus the `<a>`, not the `.card`.

Try changing the selector. From (what would be):

```
.card:focus {
```

To:

```
a:focus .card {
```

Demo:

```css
.card {
     height: 200px;
     width: 140px;
    /* margin: 20px;
     */
     overflow: hidden;
     transition: box-shadow 0.15s ease-out, transform 0.25s ease;
     perspective: 600px;
     border-radius: 5px;

}
a:focus .card {
     transform: scale(1.1);
     box-shadow: none;
}
 .card.hover--ending {
     transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<input value="click me and hit tab">
<a href="/hello">
<article class="card">
      <image type="image" src="https://icdn6.digitaltrends.com/image/google_1998-316x95.jpg" class="card__image posterImage focusable" />
 </article>
 </a>
```

Comment: `a:focus`? What is it supposed to do? :D

Comment: Hum... focus on the `<a>`?

Comment: Oh - I see; I'm not used to the fact `a` could gain a focus, I believe it's not a standard behaviour. (or maybe that's just because I'm a Mac user; it doesn't work here in Safari and Firefox for Mac at least)

Comment: Really? As far as I know they are focusable (like when you start to hit tab on a google results page). [This answer from 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1600194/1850609) seems to confirm my "feeling".

Comment: @nicael so how could someone navigate using a keyboard only(no mouse) ?