# why background color not change on focus of div?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have `div` in which I have `input` and button .I want to change the `background-color` of parent `div` when i focused to `input` div .but it is not working .Can we do this using `css not javascript`.

I tried like this

```
.a:focus{
  background-color:red;
  border:2px solid grey;
}
```

But it not work why ?

I want when I `focus` to `input` field than parent `div` which have class `"a"` will become `background-color:red` and border become red

here is my code
https://jsbin.com/kimejehane/1/edit?html,css,output

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
      <input type="text">
      <button>aa</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: try `input:focus{
  background-color:red;
  border:2px solid grey;
}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which HTML elements can receive focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus)

Comment: @DogukanCavus it only change the background of input to whole div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change background of parant div having class b, then try out this.

```
.b:focus-within {
  background-color:red;
  border:2px solid grey;
}
```

Comment: This is still a Working Draft in CSS Selectors Level 4 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within