# Keypress action query using jQuery class attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing the view behavior using `jQuery`. I can input directly to the table `td`. I want to give an event when inputting to this `td`.

But the event is not recognized, what should I do?

Here is the code:

```
<div class="a">
   <table class="tb">
      <tr>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(".a table tr td").on('keypress', function(event){
      console.log(event);
   });
</script>
```

It is an event required only on the page, so it is difficult to modify the common `jQuery` code that draws and enters the table.

Comment: How are you 'inputting' anything in to the `td` when it's not an editable field?

Comment: Also, the jQuery is missing a `"` and closing `});`

Comment: @Rory McCrossan There is a thing that makes input to td separately in jQuery common part.  I'm sorry, but I can't seem to upload that part.

Comment: And because the development environment is an internal network, it cannot be connected to the outside, so there was a typo in that part while writing it with a smartphone.

Comment: You are missing a `"` : `$(".a table tr td▶️"◀️)`

Comment: @Abd Elbeltaji Sorry, I missed that part because I was writing on my smartphone.  Edited in the text

Comment: @limsrs You still have an issue with your markup: you are closing a `<tr>` with a `</td>`

Comment: Does this help?   [Delegated Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Note that `keypress`  works for editable inputs not label or td or...

Comment: @Alireza Ahmadi Are you unable to use keypress as well as keydown?

Comment: @limsrs I'm not pointing `grammar mistakes, these are `syntax` errors. They can be the reason behind your issue, It's not that I'm trying to keep pointing mistakes, I'm trying to minimize the error margin to make sure that we reach the real reason behind your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/):

> A keypress event handler can be attached to any element, **but the event**
> **is only sent to the element that has the focus**

So you need to have focusable element, see this to know what are the focusable element: [Which HTML elements can receive focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus)

If I have `textbox` in `td` everything going to be fine:

```js
$(".a table tr td").on('keypress', function (event) {
  console.log(event.key);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="a">
        <table class="tb">
            <tr>
                <td><input /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: @limsrs Yes also `keypress` need focusable element

Comment: I made it possible to receive input in td using script code.  I do not know the details because I did not develop the part, but the conclusion is that the grammar you pointed out is because I made a typo while writing it using a smartphone, and it is written normally in the place where it is actually developed.  Also, it is written without input in td.

Comment: @limsrs So now your problem has been solved? Is there any question?

Comment: I think I'll have to try adding elements after talking with my supervisor tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The below code works, so if it doesn't work in your case, that probably means that the `<input>` field is not yet added by your other "common" code, at the time you add the `keypress` listener.

So the solution should be to first add the `<input>` fields, and after that you execute your key handler code.

```
<div class="a">
  <table class="tb">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Execute this AFTER the input fields have been added

```
$(".a table tr td").on("keypress", function (event) {
  console.log(event.key);
});
```

Working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/081cL2xu/