# How to focus to previous or next focusable sibling or related element

Tags: javascript, dom, focus

I want to navigate focus between elements in my web application using up or down keys (instead of just <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift + Tab</kbd>). I'm able to do this by using the following helpers:

```js
export function focusPrevious(focused, lockParent = false) {
    let previousSibling = focused.previousElementSibling;
    if (previousSibling == null) {
        if (!lockParent) {
            focusPrevious(focused.parentElement, lockParent);
            return;
        }
        previousSibling = focused.parentElement.lastElementChild;
    }
    previousSibling.focus();
}

export function focusNext(focused, lockParent = false) {
    let nextSibling = focused.nextElementSibling;
    if (nextSibling == null) {
        if (!lockParent) {
            focusNext(focused.parentElement, lockParent);
            return;
        }
        nextSibling = focused.parentElement.firstElementChild;
    }
    nextSibling.focus();
}
```

However, this is problematic. It may end up focusing non-focusable elements, and doesn't navigate cleverly. For example, it may end up focusing a non-focusable text area `<div>`. Is there a better solution?

Comment: You may want to filter the next or previous sibling based on the "focusability" of the element. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus/1600194#1600194) to get an idea on how to detect if an element is focusable or not

Comment: before you do this, consider that the arrow keys are used to switch between options, for example in a select list or a group of radio buttons. Don't make it harder for users that are relying on the keyboard to navigate

Answer (score 0):

I've not found any built-in way of doing this, so I had to use the NPM package [focus-lock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/focus-lock):

```
import {focusNextElement, focusPrevElement} from '../focuslock/index.js';
```

These functions worked fine, and only navigated elements from the web page, or limited to specified container, as expected.

Since I'm not directly using a NPM package for my project this time, I had to precompile the `focus-lock` package (`npm run build` on their GitHub repository), pick the `es2015` build, remove the unneeded `d.ts` files and add `.js` extension to all `import`s.