# How to react to blur/unfocus in a QCard?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, blur, quasar-framework

I have a QCard and would like to trigger an action when it becomes inactive (loses focus)

```html
<q-card bordered flat v-for="pill in loadedPerson?.Pills" :key="pill.ID" class="pill text-center bg-blue-1"
    @blur="updatePill">
    <q-card-section class="q-pb-none">
        <div class="text-h4 text-bold">{{ pill.Name }}</div>
    </q-card-section>
    <q-card-section class="flex row q-pt-none flex-center items-center">
        <q-input maxlength="2" size="2" dense borderless v-model="pill.Amount"
            class="text-h4 text-bold amountPills"></q-input>
        <q-icon size="xl" name="las la-plus-circle" class="cursor-pointer" @click="pill.Amount++"></q-icon>
        <q-icon size="xl" name="las la-minus-circle" class="cursor-pointer" @click="pill.Amount--"></q-icon>
    </q-card-section>
</q-card>
```

I expected `@blur` to trigger `updatePill` when I leave the QCard but no, nothing happens (and no relevant message is emitted either). I also tried `onfocusout="updatePill"` but again - no reaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None-input HTML elements [do not accept focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus) by default. To make them focusable, specify their `tabindex` prop.

```html
<div> not focusable </div>
<div tabindex="0"> focusable </div>
```

At the end of the day, `q-card` is a `div`, so you can leverage the same mechanism:

```js
<template>
<q-card
  bordered
  flat
  v-for="pill in loadedPerson?.Pills" :key="pill.ID"
  class="pill text-center bg-blue-1"
  @blur="updatePill(pill)"
  tabindex="0"
>
  <q-card-section class="q-pb-none">
    <div class="text-h4 text-bold">{{ pill.Name }}</div>
  </q-card-section>
  <q-card-section class="flex row q-pt-none flex-center items-center">
    <q-input maxlength="2" size="2" dense borderless v-model="pill.Amount"
             class="text-h4 text-bold amountPills"></q-input>
    <q-icon size="xl" name="las la-plus-circle" class="cursor-pointer" @click="pill.Amount++"></q-icon>
    <q-icon size="xl" name="las la-minus-circle" class="cursor-pointer" @click="pill.Amount--"></q-icon>
  </q-card-section>
</q-card>
</template>

<script setup>
const loadedPerson = {
  Pills: [
    {
      ID: '1',
      Name: 'Name 1',
      Amount: 11,
    },
    {
      ID: '2',
      Name: 'Name 2',
      Amount: 12,
    },
  ],
};

function updatePill(pill) {
  console.log('-> updatePill', pill);
}
</script>
```