# How to display character count inside textarea in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, focus, textarea

I've been trying to make a "fake" textarea to show character count "inside" of my textarea, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0VPM.png), but can't figure out how to make it focus properly.

My solution was to create a parent div with textarea styles, a textarea with no styling and a character counter to make a fake textarea:

```
<div> // textarea styling
  <textarea />
  <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>{counter}/2000</div>
</div>
```

It looks like the example above, but I have problems with focusing on the parent div. I need to visually show that it is in focus.
I've used a useRef hook to focus the parent div but it doesn't work.

```
const ref = useRef(null);

<div ref={ref}>
  <textarea onClick={() => ref.current.focus()} />
  //...
</div>
```

Here is an example https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/custom-textarea-ypl4rj

Is it even possible to trigger a focus state for a div? Maybe I'm using a wrong event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all HTML elements can receive focus - see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1600194).

Instead, change the style of `ref-parent` to use `:focus-within` instead of `:focus` ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/custom-textarea-forked-p48jzm?file=%2Fsrc%2Fstyles.css%3A21%2C2&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls1w041n00073b6l9hn2fvv7%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls1w041n00033b6lf7e9o6k1%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls1w041n00043b6lfjgdx6kk%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls1w041n00063b6l4at3iwhk%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cls1w041n00033b6lf7e9o6k1%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls1w041n00033b6lf7e9o6k1%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls1w9pj900023b6ql5xkpibb%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A21%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A2%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A21%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A2%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fstyles.css%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cls1w9pj900023b6ql5xkpibb%2522%257D%252C%2522cls1w041n00063b6l4at3iwhk%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls1w041n00053b6l2op8xd0q%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls1w041n00063b6l4at3iwhk%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cls1w041n00053b6l2op8xd0q%2522%257D%252C%2522cls1w041n00043b6lfjgdx6kk%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls1w041n00043b6lfjgdx6kk%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)):

```
.ref-parent:focus-within {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: I've tried to use focus-within before but it didn't work for me... Now it works just like I wanted, thank you!